# Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

Is there a null coalescing operator in Javascript?

For example, in C#, I can do this:

```
String someString = null;
var whatIWant = someString ?? "Cookies!";
```

The best approximation I can figure out for Javascript is using the conditional operator:

```
var someString = null;
var whatIWant = someString ? someString : 'Cookies!';
```

Which is sorta icky IMHO. Can I do better?

Comment: note from 2018:  `x ?? y` syntax is now in stage 1 proposal status - [nullish coalescing](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing)

Comment: There is now a [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) which incorporates this exact syntax.

Comment: Note from 2019: now is stage 3 status!

Comment: Note from later in 2019: Nullish coalescing is available in TypeScript 3.7!

Comment: Note from January 2020: Nullish coalescing operator is available natively in Firefox 72 but optional chaining operator is still not.

Comment: The nullish coalescing operator (`x ?? y`) and optional chaining operator (`user.address?.street`) are now both Stage 4.  Here's a good description about what that means: 

https://2ality.com/2015/11/tc39-process.html#stage-4%3A-finished .

Answer (score 2318, accepted):

**Update**

JavaScript now supports the [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator). It returns its right-hand-side operand when its left-hand-side operand is `null` or `undefined`, and otherwise returns its left-hand-side operand.

**Old Answer**

Please check compatibility before using it.

---

The JavaScript equivalent of the C# null coalescing operator (`??`) is using a logical OR (`||`):

```
var whatIWant = someString || "Cookies!";
```

There are cases (clarified below) that the behaviour won't match that of C#, but this is the general, terse way of assigning default/alternative values in JavaScript.

---

### Clarification

Regardless of the type of the first operand, if casting it to a Boolean results in `false`, the assignment will use the second operand. Beware of all the cases below:

```
alert(Boolean(null)); // false
alert(Boolean(undefined)); // false
alert(Boolean(0)); // false
alert(Boolean("")); // false
alert(Boolean("false")); // true -- gotcha! :)
```

This means:

```
var whatIWant = null || new ShinyObject(); // is a new shiny object
var whatIWant = undefined || "well defined"; // is "well defined"
var whatIWant = 0 || 42; // is 42
var whatIWant = "" || "a million bucks"; // is "a million bucks"
var whatIWant = "false" || "no way"; // is "false"
```

Comment: Strings like "false", "undefined", "null", "0", "empty", "deleted" are all true since they are non-empty strings.

Comment: Of note is that `||` returns the first "truey" value or the last "falsey" one (if none can evaluate to true) and that `&&` works in the opposite way: returning the last truey value or the first falsey one.

Comment: @JustinJohnson makes a good point. This answer compares all three: [`??` vs `||` vs `&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143185/8910547).

Answer (score 81):

```
function coalesce() {
    var len = arguments.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] !== null && arguments[i] !== undefined) {
            return arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var xyz = {};
xyz.val = coalesce(null, undefined, xyz.val, 5);

// xyz.val now contains 5
```

this solution works like the SQL coalesce function, it accepts any number of arguments, and returns null if none of them have a value.  It behaves like the C# ?? operator in the sense that "", false, and 0 are considered NOT NULL and therefore count as actual values.  If you come from a .net background, this will be the most natural feeling solution.

Comment: Apologies for such a late addition, but I just wanted to note for completeness that this solution does have the caveat that it has no short-circuit evaluation; if your arguments are function calls then they will **all** be evaluated regardless of whether their value is returned, which differs from the behaviour of the logical OR operator, so is worth noting.

Answer (score 75):

Yes, it is coming soon. See [proposal here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) and [implementation status here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing/issues/29).

It looks like this:

```
x ?? y
```

### Example

```
const response = {
  settings: {
    nullValue: null,
    height: 400,
    animationDuration: 0,
    headerText: '',
    showSplashScreen: false
  }
};

const undefinedValue = response.settings?.undefinedValue ?? 'some other default'; // result: 'some other default'
const nullValue = response.settings?.nullValue ?? 'some other default'; // result: 'some other default'
const headerText = response.settings?.headerText ?? 'Hello, world!'; // result: ''
const animationDuration = response.settings?.animationDuration ?? 300; // result: 0
const showSplashScreen = response.settings?.showSplashScreen ?? true; // result: false
```

Answer (score 46):

If `||` as a replacement of C#'s `??` isn't good enough in your case, because it swallows empty strings and zeros, you can always write your own function:

```
 function $N(value, ifnull) {
    if (value === null || value === undefined)
      return ifnull;
    return value;
 }

 var whatIWant = $N(someString, 'Cookies!');
```

Comment: alert(null || '') still alerts an empty string, and I think I actually like that alert('' || 'blah') alerts blah rather than an empty string - good to know though! (+1)

Comment: I think I might actually prefer defining a function that returns `false` if (strictly) null/undefined and `true` otherwise - using that with a logical or; it could be more readable than many nested functions calls. e.g. `$N(a) || $N(b) || $N(c) || d` is more readable than `$N($N($N(a, b), c), d)`.

Answer (score 16):

Nobody has mentioned in here the potential for `NaN`, which--to me--is also a null-ish value. So, I thought I'd add my two-cents.

For the given code:

```
var a,
    b = null,
    c = parseInt('Not a number'),
    d = 0,
    e = '',
    f = 1
;
```

If you were to use the `||` operator, you get the first non-false value:

```
var result = a || b || c || d || e || f; // result === 1
```

If you use the new `??` (null coalescing) operator, you will get `c`, which has the value: `NaN`

```
vas result = a ?? b ?? c ?? d ?? e ?? f; // result === NaN
```

**Neither** of these seem right to me.  In my own little world of coalesce logic, which may differ from your world, I consider undefined, null, and NaN as all being "null-ish".  So, I would expect to get back `d` (zero) from the coalesce method.

If anyone's brain works like mine, and you want to exclude `NaN`, then this custom `coalesce` method (unlike [the one posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22265471/482256)) will accomplish that:

```
function coalesce() {
    var i, undefined, arg;

    for( i=0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        arg = arguments[i];
        if( arg !== null && arg !== undefined
            && (typeof arg !== 'number' || arg.toString() !== 'NaN') ) {
            return arg;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

For those who want the code as short as possible, and don't mind a little lack of clarity, you can also use this as suggested by @impinball. This takes advantage of the fact that NaN is never equal to NaN.  You can read up more on that here: [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

```
function coalesce() {
    var i, arg;

    for( i=0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        arg = arguments[i];
        if( arg != null && arg === arg ) { //arg === arg is false for NaN
            return arg;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Best practices - treat arguments as array-like, take advantage of NaN !== NaN (`typeof` + `num.toString() === 'NaN'` is redundant), store current argument in variable instead of `arguments[i]`.

Answer (score 10):

### `??` vs `||` vs `&&`

None of the other answers compares all three of these. Since [Justin Johnson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript#comment4299407_476445) has so many votes, and since [double question mark vs && in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64385309/8910547) was marked a duplicate of this one, it makes sense to include `&&` in an answer.

First in words, inspired by Justin Johnson's comment:

- `||` returns the first "truey" value, else the last value whatever it is.
- `&&` returns the first "falsey" value, else the last value whatever it is.
- `??` returns the first non-null, non-undefined value, else the last value, whatever it is.

Then, demonstrated in live code:

```js
let F1,
    F2 = null,
    F3 = 0,
    F4 = '',
    F5 = parseInt('Not a number (NaN)'),
    T1 = 3,
    T2 = 8

console.log( F1 || F2 || F3 || F4 || F5 || T1 || T2 ) // 3 (T1)
console.log( F1 || F2 || F3 || F4 || F5 )             // NaN (F5)

console.log( T1 && T2 && F1 && F2 && F3 && F4 && F5 ) // undefined (F1)
console.log( T1 && T2 )                               // 8 (T2)

console.log( F1 ?? F2 ?? F3 ?? F4 ?? F5 ?? T1 )       // 0 (F3)
console.log( F1 ?? F2)                                // null (F2)
```

Answer (score 8):

## Logical nullish assignment, 2020+ solution

A new operator is currently being added to the browsers, `??=`. This combines the null coalescing operator `??` with the assignment operator `=`.

> NOTE: This is not common in public browser versions *yet*. Will update as availability changes.

`??=` checks if the variable is undefined or null, short-circuiting if already defined. If not, the right-side value is assigned to the variable.

#### Basic Examples

```
let a          // undefined
let b = null
let c = false

a ??= true  // true
b ??= true  // true
c ??= true  // false
```

#### Object/Array Examples

```
let x = ["foo"]
let y = { foo: "fizz" }

x[0] ??= "bar"  // "foo"
x[1] ??= "bar"  // "bar"

y.foo ??= "buzz"  // "fizz"
y.bar ??= "buzz"  // "buzz"

x  // Array [ "foo", "bar" ]
y  // Object { foo: "fizz", bar: "buzz" }
```

[Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_logical_nullish_assignment) Jan '22 - 89%

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and its [proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-nullish-coalescing/) is [Stage 4](https://tc39.es/process-document/) now. This means that the proposal is ready for inclusion in the formal ECMAScript standard. You can already use it in recent desktop versions of Chrome, Edge and Firefox, but we will have to wait for a bit longer until this feature reaches cross-browser stability.

Have a look at the following example to demonstrate its behavior:

```js
// note: this will work only if you're running latest versions of aforementioned browsers
const var1 = undefined;
const var2 = "fallback value";

const result = var1 ?? var2;
console.log(`Nullish coalescing results in: ${result}`);
```

Previous example is equivalent to:

```js
const var1 = undefined;
const var2 = "fallback value";

const result = (var1 !== null && var1 !== undefined) ?
    var1 :
    var2;
console.log(`Nullish coalescing results in: ${result}`);
```

Note that *nullish coalescing* will **not** threat *falsy* values the way the `||` operator did (it only checks for `undefined` or `null` values), hence the following snippet will act as follows:

```js
// note: this will work only if you're running latest versions of aforementioned browsers
const var1 = ""; // empty string
const var2 = "fallback value";

const result = var1 ?? var2;
console.log(`Nullish coalescing results in: ${result}`);
```

---

For TypesScript users, starting off [TypeScript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing), this feature is also available now.

Comment: This is gigantic!

Answer (score 5):

After reading your clarification, @Ates Goral's answer provides how to perform the same operation you're doing in C# in JavaScript.

@Gumbo's answer provides the best way to check for null; however, it's important to note the difference in `==` versus `===` in JavaScript *especially* when it comes to issues of checking for `undefined` and/or `null`.

There's a really good article about the difference in two terms [here](http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html). Basically, understand that if you use `==` instead of `===`, JavaScript will try to coalesce the values you're comparing and return what the result of the comparison *after* this coalescence.

Answer (score 5):

beware of the JavaScript specific definition of null. there are two definitions for "no value" in javascript.
1. Null: when a variable is null, it means it contains no data in it, but the variable is already defined in the code. like this:

```
var myEmptyValue = 1;
myEmptyValue = null;
if ( myEmptyValue === null ) { window.alert('it is null'); }
// alerts
```

in such case, the type of your variable is actually Object. test it.

```
window.alert(typeof myEmptyValue); // prints Object
```

2. Undefined: when a variable has not been defined before in the code, and as expected, it does not contain any value. like this:

   ```
   if ( myUndefinedValue === undefined ) { window.alert('it is undefined'); }
   // alerts
   ```

if such case, the type of your variable is 'undefined'.

notice that if you use the type-converting comparison operator (==), JavaScript will act equally for both of these empty-values. to distinguish between them, always use the type-strict comparison operator (===).

Comment: Actually, null is a value. It's a special value of type Object. A variable being set to null means it contains data, the data being a reference to the null object. A variable can be defined with value undefined in your code. This is not the same as the variable not being declared.

Comment: The actual difference between a variable being declared or not: alert(window.test)/*undefined*/; alert("test" in window)/*false*/; window.test = undefined; alert(window.test)/*undefined*/; alert("test" in window)/*true*/; for (var p in window) {/*p can be "test"*/}

Comment: however (a bit paradoxal) you can **define** a variable with the **undefined** value `var u = undefined;`

Comment: @AtesGoral re null. While what you say is true, *by convention*, "null" represents *"the absence of (useful) data"*. Hence it is considered to be "no data". And lets not forget that this is an answer to a question about "a null coalescing operator"; in this context, null is definitely treated as "no data" - regardless of how it is represented internally.

Answer (score 4):

There are two items here:

1. Logical OR

const foo = '' || 'default string';

console.log(foo); // output is 'default string'

2. Nullish coalescing operator

const foo = '' ?? 'default string';

console.log(foo); // output is empty string i.e. ''

The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: Before the release of the operator, this talk was necessary.  But since your answer is just inferior to and much later in time than @faithful's answer, I'd argue you had too much talk.

Answer (score 3):

Note that React's `create-react-app` tool-chain supports the null-coalescing since [version 3.3.0 (released 5.12.2019)](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.3.0). From the release notes:

> Optional Chaining and Nullish Coalescing Operators
>
> We now support the optional chaining and nullish coalescing operators!
>
> ```
> // Optional chaining
> a?.(); // undefined if `a` is null/undefined
> b?.c; // undefined if `b` is null/undefined
>
> // Nullish coalescing
> undefined ?? 'some other default'; // result: 'some other default'
> null ?? 'some other default'; // result: 'some other default'
> '' ?? 'some other default'; // result: ''
> 0 ?? 300; // result: 0
> false ?? true; // result: false
> ```

This said, in case you use `create-react-app` 3.3.0+ you can start using the null-coalesce operator already today in your React apps.

Answer (score 2):

It will hopefully be available soon in Javascript, as it is in proposal phase as of Apr, 2020. You can monitor the status here for compatibility and support - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

For people using Typescript, you can use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) from [Typescript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)

From the docs -

> You can think of this feature - the `??` operator - as a way to “fall
>   back” to a default value when dealing with `null` or `undefined`. When we
>   write code like
>
> `let x = foo ?? bar();`
>
> this is a new way to say that the value `foo` will be used when it’s “present”; but when it’s `null` or `undefined`,
>   calculate `bar()` in its place.

Answer (score 1):

Need to support old browser and have a object hierarchy

```
body.head.eyes[0]  //body, head, eyes  may be null
```

may use this,

```
(((body||{}) .head||{}) .eyes||[])[0] ||'left eye'
```

Answer (score 1):

**ECMAScript 2021** enabled two new features:

1. **Nullish coalescing operator (??)** which is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is either null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

```js
let b = undefined ?? 5;

console.log(b); // 5
```

2. **Logical nullish assignment (x ??= y)** operator which only assigns if x has a nullish value (null or undefined).

```js
const car = {speed : 20};
car.speed ??= 5;
console.log(car.speed);
car.name ??= "reno";
console.log(car.name);
```

More about Logical nullish assignment can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

More about Nullish coalescing operator can be found here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 0):

Now it has full support in latest version of major browsers like Chrome, Edge, Firefox , Safari etc. Here's the comparison between the null operator and Nullish Coalescing Operator

```
const response = {
        settings: {
            nullValue: null,
            height: 400,
            animationDuration: 0,
            headerText: '',
            showSplashScreen: false
        }
    };
    /* OR Operator */
    const undefinedValue = response.settings.undefinedValue || 'Default Value'; // 'Default Value'
    const nullValue = response.settings.nullValue || 'Default Value'; // 'Default Value'
    const headerText = response.settings.headerText || 'Hello, world!'; //  'Hello, world!'
    const animationDuration = response.settings.animationDuration || 300; //  300
    const showSplashScreen = response.settings.showSplashScreen || true; //  true
    /* Nullish Coalescing Operator */
    const undefinedValue = response.settings.undefinedValue ?? 'Default Value'; // 'Default Value'
    const nullValue = response.settings.nullValue ?? ''Default Value'; // 'Default Value'
    const headerText = response.settings.headerText ?? 'Hello, world!'; // ''
    const animationDuration = response.settings.animationDuration ?? 300; // 0
    const showSplashScreen = response.settings.showSplashScreen ?? true; //  false
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are using Babel, need to upgrade to the latest version to use nullish coalescing (??):

> Babel 7.8.0 supports the new ECMAScript 2020 features by default: you
> don't need to enable individual plugins for nullish coalescing (??),
> optional chaining (?.) and dynamic import() anymore with preset-env

From https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/01/11/7.8.0

Answer (score 0):

### Chain multiple values / several values

- "short circuit" is enabled: do not evaluate any further if one of the first values is valid
- that means order matters, the most left values are prioritized

```js
const value = first ?? second ?? third ?? "default";
```

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to check if an input is null and then use the value accordingly. This is my code.

```
let valueToBeConsidered = !inputValue ? "trueCondition" : "falseCondition",
```

So if inputValue is null then valueToBeConsidered = falseCondition and if inputValue has a value then valueToBeConsidered = trueCondition