# JavaScript object definition conditionals - which is better?

Tags: javascript, object

I've come across two different ways to define/name objects and functions in JavaScript that first check for the existence of the name before using it.  The issue is, I don't know which one is better (from speed and usability standpoints) and it's impossible to use the boolean operators in a Google search to figure it out.

The first one I see most often:

```
var myNewObject = myNewObject ? myNewObject : function () {
    // Code goes here.
};
```

The second one seems more concise, but I've only seen it one or two places, so I don't know if there's a standard or even a name for it:

```
var myNewObject = myNewObject || function() {
    // Code goes here.
};
```

Functionally, they both do the same thing and they both seem to work in every browser I can test in.  My question is this - which is better and why?  Also, while the first definition is essentially a single-line conditional ... what is the second one called?

Comment: the second one is more common imho. At least for people who know the language...

Comment: Cool, does anyone know if this works also with prototype: i.e. Array.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach || function(... I'm asking because on Mozilla website they use a normal if(!Array.prototype.forEach) Array.prototype.forEach = function(...

Comment: @Marco Demaio Following the same logic is *should* work.  I'd suggest slapping it in a test script and seeing if it does.  You're still defining an object method ... it just happens to be in a specific namespace already.

Comment: it works, but it might not be optimized. I added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would choose the latter if only for the fact that you type `myNewObject` twice instead of thrice.

> Also, while the first definition is essentially a single-line conditional ... what is the second one called?

[Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since you also gave me the name of the second approach.  It would have saved so much time had I know what it was called ... I didn't know it was a legitimate approach, just that it seemed to work.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the second example, which is described as (Minimum Eval).  Its simpler and seems more readable.

It's just like getting an event from onClick method across multiple browsers.

```
element.onclick = function (evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The latter, it's *similar* to the null coalesce operator in c# `??` when used in that manner

see: [Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript)

Comment: Note that is not completely equivalent, `??` in C# it will return the default value only when its left operand value is `null`, in JavaScript `||` will do it when its first operand is *falsy*, falsy values are: `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, empty string, and `false`.

Comment: @CMS, yeah, hence the link for clarification.  I should have wrote that it's *similar* to the `??` operator

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I see the second approach more often, and (for my part) I feel it's more clear, concise, and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods work.
But I think the most optimized version is to simply use a normal if test like:

```
if(!myNewObject)
   myNewObject = ...
```

Doing in any one of the method you suggest in your answer, it might involve an unnecessary reassignment every time the function/object is already defined. I mean if myNewObject is already defined, the JavaScript runtime would have to perform an unnecessary reassignment `myNewObject = myNewObject` (unless the runtime doesn't optimize it out).

On Mozilla website they suggest to use a simple if, [view this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/forEach).