# Init object in javascript using || operator

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I see in javascript code something like this:

```
var myObj = myObj || {};
```

So, what actually happen here? I suppose || operator returns true or false, but it's not correct.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `||` operator returns the left operand if it evaluates as true, otherwise it evaluates and returns the right operand.  In other words, `a || b` is equivalent to `a ? a : b` except that `a` is only evaluated once.

Comment: +1 also called *null coalescing operator* in JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript/476445#476445

Comment: No, it can just be used as a *replacement* for C#'s null coalescing operator (`??`).  :)  I've never heard `||` called the "null coalescing operator;" it's always been the "logical or" operator.

Comment: agreed. from OP's previous questions he is from ASP.NET background and thats why this clarification.

Answer (score 6):

To understand the || operator, let's first look at a fairly basic example. The logical OR operator may be used to provide a default value for a defined variable as follows:

```
 var bar = false,  
 foobar = 5,  
 foo = bar || foobar; // foo = 5
```

In this case, foo will only be assigned the value of foobar if bar is considered falsy. A falsy value could be considered being equal to 0, false, undefined, null, NaN or empty (e.g "").

Answer (score 3):

This initializes myObj unless it is already defined.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this construct to get the object that is not `null`, `undefined`, etc. This is used in cases where you use `myObj` later on in the code which requires it to be an object. If, for some reason, `myObj` is undefined prior to this line, re-assigning it leaves it `undefined` or `null`, in which case it would be assigned `{}`.

You can think of this as:

```
// If the object is already defined
if (myObj)
    var myObj = myObj;
// It was undefined or null, so assign an empty object to it.
else
    var myObj = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

The OR op (||) will return the first non-empty/false parameter.

In the case specified, if myObj is false or null, it will be set to an empty object (the {} brackets are used to create objects)

Answer (score 1):

|| is a short circuit operator. If the first operand evaluates to true the second is not evaluated.

Thus JS `a || b` is something like c# `a ?? b`

Answer (score 0):

if `myObj` is undefined or null then it evaluates the expression on the right side of `||` which creates a new empty object

so `myObj` is either myObj if it is not null or an empty object if myObj is null

i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Also if the value of `myObj` was false or 0 or NaN or the empty string it will also cause the variable to then be assigned a new object.  It's not **just** undefined or null.  There are 6 falsy things in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ray Toal: thanks for the addition