# When and why use JS null coalescing operator

Tags: javascript, null-coalescing-operator

I was trying to understand the point of `var myObj = myObj || {};` and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118575/init-object-in-javascript-using-operator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript/476445#476445) article explaining it. But I still don't see the situation in which I'd need it. Those articles seem to address the actual logic of it as its equivalence to `a ? a : b`- I get that.

For example, I'm creating a HUD for my game,

```
game.HUD = game.HUD || {}; 

game.HUD.Container = me.Container.extend({
//...
```

Why can't I just create the object without using `game.HUD = game.HUD || {};`?

Comment: I'm not sure `var x = x || y` has any useful meaning. `var x = y || z` does, though.

Comment: Just drop the line and you will immediately see why you need it.

Comment: Incase game.HUD is already defined you do not destroy the exsisting data or set it as an array like object.

Comment: Just for future reference, the name of the operator is "logical OR".

Answer (score 3):

If you know you need to initialize `game.HUD` for certain, then you don't need to use your snippet.

If there's a possibility that `game.HUD` held a previous value that you don't want to overwrite, then that's when you would use your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly a safety thing. You want:

1. ... the following code to be able to use `game.HUD` regardless of whether it was previously initialized
2. ... any fields that *were* assigned if `game.HUD` *was* already initialized to remain.

If `game.HUD` already existed, then

```
game.HUD = {};
```

would wipe out any data assigned to it.

```
game.HUD = game.HUD || {};
```

initializes it *if necessary*, and otherwise leaves it alone, so that either way

```
game.HUD.Container = ...
```

works.