# How to mimick the functionality of the SQL Coalesce statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coalesce

I was wondering if there is a way in javascript to have logic similar to the coalesce statement in sql which will return data in a specified order like this:

```
Select top 1 Coalesce(ColA, ColB, "No Data Found") from TableA;
```

is there an elegant way to deal with null values in Javascript, the same way that sql returns results in the above statement?

i know i could technically have a switch statement, but this would require some possibly unnecessary code

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [null coalescing operator for javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an OR.

```
 var someVar = null || value;
 var otherVar = null || variableThatEvaluatesToNull || functionThatEvaluatesToNull() || value;
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `||` are values like `0`, which may be desired.  You could write your own javascript function to simulate COALESCE.

```
function Coalesce() {
  var args = Coalesce.arguments;

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
    if (null !== args[i])
      return args[i];
  }

  return null;  // No non-null values found, return null
}
```

Which you could then call as expected:

```
var myNonNullValue = Coalesce(null, objectA, objectB, "defaultValue");
```

Comment: `null !== undefined` would be true...so may want to add an undefined check as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "falsy" values and the `||` operator (logical OR):

```
var foo = bar || baz;
```

Above would assign the value of `bar` to `foo` if `bar` evaluates to a "truthy" value and `baz` otherwise (e.g. if `bar` is undefined, null, false etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a link to basically the same question:  [Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript)

That's call null coalescing.  In C#, there's a null coalesce operator "??" and that's what the original asker of the linked question was referring to.