# javascript null value in string

Tags: javascript

In javascript I have the following:

```
var inf = id + '|' + city ;
```

if id or city are null then inf will be null.

Is there any slick way of saying if id or city are null make then blank.

I know in c# you can do the following:

```
var inf = (id ?? "") + (city ?? "");
```

Any similar method in javascript?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Please provide one ore more example values for `inf`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [null coalescing operator for javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var inf = (id == null ? '' : id) + '|' + (city == null ? '' : city)
```

Comment: That's just a longer way to do what Elliot is doing in his answer

Comment: I have no idea why this was accepted instead of pysho's answer.

Comment: Sometimes longer and easier to read and understand answers are better than shorter and cryptic ones. As long as it's not wrong, why do people care.

Answer (score 22):

How about:

```
var inf = [id, city].join('|');
```

EDIT:
You can remove the "blank" parts before joining, so that if only one of id and city is null, inf will just contain that part and if both are null inf will be empty.

```
var inf = _([id, city]).compact().join('|'); // underscore.js
var inf = [id, city].compact().join('|'); // sugar.js
var inf = [id, city].filter(function(str) { return str; }).join('|'); // without helpers
```

Comment: `inf` will not be blank , if `id` and `city` are `null`s.

Comment: @Engineer: Yes, it'll be `"|"`, the desired result.

Comment: @Rocket I know about "|", just read `if id or city are null then inf will be null.` of @Nate.

Answer (score 16):

Total long shot, but try this:

```
var inf = (id || "") + "|" + (city || "");
```

Comment: this will work for undefined vars, not so sure about null values.

Comment: I'd suggest adding parenthesis: `var inf = (id || "") + "|" + (city || "");`

Comment: @Rocket: Alright, thanks, although I don't think it would matter.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville it doesn't actually matter to the interpreter (since it's equivalent), but it will matter to your co-workers.

Comment: @Rocket: Oh, okay. Thanks. **nickf**: That's true, that's true. :)

Comment: @nickf It *does* make a difference. Try it.

Comment: Can you please explain the above. Why || ?

Comment: @Nate: It's an 'or' operator, which means this: `var inf = (id if id is not undefined, otherwise use "") + "|" + (city if city is not undefined, otherwise use "")`

Comment: @EliranMalka: This works for any value evaluating to `false`. So also `0`, which might not be wanted.

Comment: @Nate Pet - all javascript expressions return a boolean value, thus if the check using a boolean operator (||) will be evaluated to false, the next expression will be evaluated (an empty string assignment).

Comment: @EliranMalka: Careful with your wording. `1+1` returns `2` which is not a boolean value.

Comment: @EliranMalka: Not quite.  It's not that all expressions *return* a boolean, it's that all expressions can be *converted* to a boolean.

Comment: @nickf: Without parenthesis, it's interpreted as `inf = (id) || ("" + "|" + city) || ("");`

Answer (score 1):

```
function nullToStr(str) {
    return !str || 0 === str.length ? '' : str;
}
```

usage:

```
console.log(nullToStr(null);
```

```js
        function nullToStr(str) {
    return !str || 0 === str.length ? '' : str;
}

console.log(`The value which was null = ${nullToStr(null)}`);
console.log(`The value which was null = ${nullToStr(undefined)}`);
console.log(`The value which was null = ${nullToStr('')}`);
console.log(`The value which was null = ${nullToStr('asdasd')}`);
```

I think it will help and is much easier to use. Obviously, it is based on the other answers i found in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inf = (id && city) ? (id+"|"+city) : "";
```

Comment: What if one or the other is null?  He wanted each variable replaced with `""` if it was null, not the whole thing.

Comment: @Rocket "if id or city are null then inf will be null", I think he wants empty string either one is null.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to c# `var inf = (id ?? "") + (city ?? "");` (if `id` and `city` are nullable) is

```
var inf = (id || '') + (city || '');
```

This is referred to as '[Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)'. Nullability is not an issue in javascript (in js all variables are nullable), but `id` and `city` have to be assigned (but do not need a value, as in `var id, city`).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (id != ""){
inf = id;
if (city != ""){ inf += " | " + city ;}
}
else 
inf= city;
```