# How to test the null value condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Below is the code,

```
<p id="sayHello"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yourName = window['prompt']("What is your name?");

    if (yourName != null) {
        window['document']['getElementById']("sayHello").innerHTML = "Hello " + yourName;
    } else {
        window['alert']("Please enter your name next time");
    }
</script>
```

for which, `else` block need to get executed based on the input given in `prompt`.

What should be the input in `prompt` box to test `null` value of primitive type `Null`?

Comment: `== null` / `!= null` is totally fine. What exactly is your question? Doesn't that code work?

Comment: @Bergi Trying to know, for what input, null check will be satisfies. as you said, by pressing cancel button.

Comment: @AshwinGupta I said `Null` primitive value `null`

Comment: @overexchange: Yes, [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns the `null` value when being cancelled, and comparing with `null` totally tests for that condition.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @overexchange my bad, didn't read =/

Comment: See the answer on this one, it basically says it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045805/javascript-null-value-in-string

Answer (score 0):

When you click cancel on the prompt box the else block will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [MDN window.prompt docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt):

> If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned.

So really you want to check `if (yourName !== null && yourName !== "")` since the prompt is really returning the empty string (thus causing your `else` clause to be executed incorrectly since it's passing the not null check).

Comment: Is this [code](https://github.com/shamhub/Javascript_Programming/blob/master/Topic8_DOM_Access/jstut.html) fine?

Comment: Yes, that code looks sound. It first checks if the name is empty (if so, say name is empty), then checks if it's null (if not, use the name), otherwise it says a different warning. Note that for most cases in javascript you want to use a triple-equal comparision (=== or !==) so that type checks hold as well.

Comment: You can test code in your browser's console btw. Just hit f12 and you can run the exact code. I would also recommend omitting the verbose object access when possible (eg: use window.prompt rather than window['prompt'] since you only need the second form when there are special characters like hympen).

Comment: Sorry, I meant "hyphen" as in "-"

Comment: Any example? For using bracket notation

Comment: I'm basically saying you can write `window.prompt` when the object key doesn't have special characters. You'd have to do something like `window['foo-bar']` for the 'foo-bar' key because `window.foo-bar` isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you  actualy looking for empty string.Also null is a primitive value & **null** represent an "empty" value, that is no object value is present.
So to check null we can use

```
if(somVar === null && typeof somVar ==='object')
```

So you can arrange you code as

```
var yourName = window['prompt']("What is your name?");
if (yourName === null & typeof(yourName) ==='object') {
       alert("Please enter your name next time");
    } else {
       document.getElementById("sayHello").innerHTML = "Hello " + yourName; 
    }
```

Also note this will **ONLY** test for null and will not pass for `"",undefined,false,0` & `NaN`.
Beside is there any reason to use

```
window['document']['getElementById']("sayHello")
```

when it can be done like this

```
  document.getElementById("sayHello").innerHTML
```

If you are checking for empty string , then you also have to validate that input is not empty

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n7eemhd0/1/)