# How to coalesce an array in JavaScript/CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, null, coffeescript, null-coalescing-operator

[Coalescing a static set of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript) is easy:

```
var finalValue = configValue || "default"; # JavaScript
finalValue = configValue ? "default" # CoffeeScript
```

But is there a simple way to **coalesce an array of unknown length**? The simplest I could come up with was this (CoffeeScript):

```
coalesce = (args) -> args.reduce (arg) -> arg if arg?
coalesce [1, 2] # Prints 1
```

That's fine for simple lists, but

1. ideally `coalesce` should iterate over `arguments`, but it doesn't support `reduce`, and
2. if the array contains functions, you might want to return their *return value* rather than the functions themselves (this is my use case).

Based on Guffa's solution, here's a CoffeeScript version:

```
coalesce = (args) -> args[0]() ? coalesce args[1..]
```

Test in `coffee`:

```
fun1 = ->
  console.log 1
  null
fun2 = ->
  console.log 2
  2
fun3 = ->
  console.log 3
  3
coalesce [fun1, fun2, fun3]
```

Prints

```
1 # Log
2 # Log
2 # Return value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
function coalesce(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) return null;
  var v = arr[0];
  v = (typeof v == "function" ? v() : v);
  return v | coalesce(arr.slice(1));
}
```

Example:

```
var finalValue = coalesce([ null, null, function(){ return null; }, 5 ]);
// finalValue is now 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This function works perfectly for me:

```
function coalesce(...param){
    if (param.length == 0) return null;
      return param.find(a => a !== null);
}

let value = coalesce(null, null, 1,2,3,4);
console.log('value = ', value );
```