# javascript null conditional expression

Tags: javascript, operators, null-coalescing-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [null coalescing operator for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript)

In C#, you can do this:

```
var obj = newObject ?? defaultObject;
```

That says assign `newObject` to `obj` if not null else assign `defaultObject`. How do I write this in javascript?

Comment: There's an excellent answer to this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/1010337

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it's considered an *abusage*, you can do the following:

```
var obj = newObject || defaultObject;
```

Note that if `newObject` is of any *falsy* value (such as `0` or an empty string), `defaultObject` will be returned as the value of `obj`. With this in mind, it may be preferred to use either the ternary operator or a standard if-statement.

```
var obj = ( "undefined" === typeof defaultObject ) ? defaultObject : newObject ;
```

Comment: This is *slightly* different though, as it will result in `defaultObject` for *any* false-y value of `newObject`. That is, there is no "direct"-equivalent, so the ternary (`??`) with an explicit equality might capture a given intent better...

Comment: @Lolcoder A boolean `false` is an actual false. *Falsy* values would be things like the number `0`, or an empty string.

Comment: @pst - While I agree with you, I would note that if you know in advance that `defaultObject` actually is an _object_ then it will never be falsy.