# Setting a default variable value in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a lot of front-end development and I see myself doing this a lot:

```
function doSomething(arg){
    var int = arg ? arg : 400
    //some code after
}
```

So I was wondering if the was a way to do this, but shorter and cleaner (I don't like to see `arg` twice in the same line).

I've seen some people doing something like that :

```
var int = arg || 400;
```

And since I don't know in which order I needed to place the value, I tried `arg || 400` and `400 || arg`, but it will always set `int` to the value at the right, even if `arg` is undefined.

I know in PHP you can do something like `function doSomething(arg = 400)` to set a default value and in a jQuery plugin you can use `.extend()` to have default property,  but is there a short way with a single variable? Or do i have to keep using my way?

Thank for any help and if you can give me resources, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't let falsely values bite you in the butt. If you are working with numbers, better off checking for undefined.

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/1823841) might help you to understand the **Coalesce Operator** better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's really no shorter clean way than

```
var int = arg || 400;
```

In fact, the correct way would be longer, if you want to allow arg to be passed as `0`, `false` or `""`:

```
var int = arg===undefined ? 400 : arg;
```

A slight and frequent improvement is to not declare a new variable but use the original one:

```
if (arg===undefined) arg=400;
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't check for `undefined` in that way, just to be safe. You should use `(typeof arg === 'undefined')` instead.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Just to be safe against what ? Yourself having redefined `undefined` ? It's not possible in ES5. Passing `null`?

Comment: The first one. `undefined` could be redefined by you or by someone you work with or by a library you import. It shouldn't be, but `undefined` is mutable, so...

Comment: Well, no, you can't redefine `undefined`. Try it. And even if you could, it makes no sense in trying to protect from stupid libraries, don't use those stupid libraries (supposing there is one).

Comment: Yes, you can, in IE 8, at least.

Comment: That's why I precised ES5. But do you really saw a library so stupid ? A stupid library could break your code in so many ways, there're no sense in guarding against that.

Comment: Can we code `var arg = arg===undefined ? 400 : arg;` instead of `if (arg===undefined) arg=400;`?

Comment: @JustinJohn: Yes, you can, but why would you do it? It's more complicated and does the same thing.

Comment: @Bergi Slight and frequent improvement is to not declare a new variable. If we redeclare same variable, what is additional overhead causes? The memory allocation will be same isn't it?

Comment: Just a little clarification, it is possible to change the value of the argument sent to the function?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, but it changes only the value inside the function (apart if it's an object and you change one of its properties).

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(x,y){
   if(typeof(x)==='undefined') x = 10;
   if(typeof(y)==='undefined') y = 20;

   //code goes here
}
```

Comment: typeof is not a method call

Comment: It is not being used as such here, neither is it being used as a function. The parentheses around x and y are not necessary but create no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solutions is that a value that evaluates to false (for example "false" or "0") also trigger the default value. So for every parameter that could possibly ever have a value that evaluates to false you have to check for "undefined" explicitly.

```
var int = (typeof x === 'undefined') ? default : x
```

If this is not possible you can use

```
var int = x ? x : default
OR
var int = x || default
```

Another option would be to use the arguments array and check if the parameters were given. But this can only be used if your optional parameters are the last ones.

```
function test(x, y) {
    var int1 = (arguments.length > 0) ? x : default;
    var int2 = (arguments.length > 1) ? y : default;
}
```

Comment: or skip the typeof all together and just check if it equals undefined.

Comment: @epascarello: That's not safe. `undefined` is mutable in some browsers.

Comment: Modern browsers prevent it from being overwritten. Plus in the 12 years I been coding JavaScript I have never had that happen! Now people overriding submit is a different story. And if you are really scared, store a variable that is undefined and use it.

Comment: And chart of support for Immutable undefined:  http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Immutable%20undefined The fear can die down.

Comment: @epascarello: Lots of people are still supporting IE8 and IE7. I ran into a user the other day who was still using Windows XP...

Comment: @epascrello: As long as IE7 and IE8 are used (and they are) it is not 100% safe to use "=== undefined". It doesn't matter if "undefined" is usually not redefined (and should not be), it could be and that's the point.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to the question, but why create a new variable to mirror an argument?

In this situation I would use :

```
!arg && (arg = 400);
```

However, this tests `arg` for falsity which means that the values `false`, `0`, `''`, `null` and `undefined` would all cause `arg` to be set to `400`. If this is not the desired result, perhaps a value of `0` is a valid `arg` value then I usually test `argument.length` :

```
function f (arg) {
  !arguments.length && (arg = 400);
```

This checks if **any** value was passed and sets `arg` only in the case that the call specified no arguments at all.

Only is specific instances where `0` is not a desired value would I use the construct

```
 arg || 400
```

which again suffers from the falsity test

If it is important that `arg` be numeric you could use :

```
 typeof arg !== 'number' && (arg = 400);
```

which would ensure that `arg` was a number and in the rest of the code.

In conclusion: it depends on exactly how you want to use the argument, what values are valid  and how much you trust the callers of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would check `arguments.length`:

```
var f = function(arg) {
  var myArg = arguments.length > 0 ? arg : 400;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, you can set default value to arguments the same way we do in PHP :

```
function foo( a = [], b = 'string', c = false ){}
```

Default value can also be set to a previous argument ou even a function's return value

```
function foo( a = true, b = a, c = bar() ){}
```

This will also work with ES6 compilers. The end result will look like this

```
function foo() {
  var a = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? true : arguments[0];
  var b = arguments.length <= 1 || arguments[1] === undefined ? a : arguments[1];
  var c = arguments.length <= 2 || arguments[2] === undefined ? bar() : arguments[2];
}
```