# JavaScript: Making variable into default?

Tags: javascript, html

Javascipt: Making variable into default?

I have code like this :

```
<script>
document.write(ab);
</script>
```

`ab` is a variable but it's not declared yet because I want it will be changing by Users. The default result I want it displays is `x+y` (for example as). But When Users enter any variable, the result need to be changed. For instance :

```
<script>
var ab = "The users change code";
</script>
```

The result will change is `The users change code`

So, Do you have any idea for my issue. Thank for your help.

Comment: Read any basic guide to javascript and you'll figure this out within minutes.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696642/setting-a-default-variable-value-in-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be pedant :

You said :

```
ab is a variable but it's not declared yet
```

shom's answer should work fine.

**But** if I was a robot which analyze your question :

this would **pass** although you **have** declared it :

```
    var ab=undefined;
    if (typeof ab === 'undefined')
        var ab= 'x+y';
    document.write(ab);
```

the safest way (as answering to your :"*not declared yet* "):

```
 if (!('ab' in window))
  var ab = 'x+y';
  document.write(ab);
```

Comment: If you want to use my answer in your answer, perhaps you could've added a comment instead... Should I now write another answer to elaborate on this answer?

Comment: @Shomz I'll remove your code from my answer.

Comment: It's still there, but never mind. I said this because it's happening more and more on SO lately, and I can't figure out why are people taking others' answers.

Comment: @Shomz I removed your code. and the second code is a code which the whole world ( including me) would have given . just to make it different. i will write it better and add `===` which is much more precise (and correct). no one is stealing no one's code.

Comment: It should be `if (!('ab' in window))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in various ways. A ternary is a simple one.

```
var ab=(typeof ab==='undefined'?) x+y : ab;
```

This says that if ab is undefined, set it to x+y, otherwise leave it at the current, presumably user set, value.

There may be better ways to handle all of this. Post more code if you'd like.

Comment: why do you complicate things ?

Comment: p.s. those kind of solutions are bad because of scoping issues.

Comment: @Royi I agree, that's why I solicited more code and said this whole thing could be done more cleanly. The ternary style is seen fairly often for setting defaults in my experience. I like that it looks like an assignment straight off, not an 'if'.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof ab == 'undefined')
    var ab = 'x+y';
document.write(ab);
```