# I am trying to analyze the following js code. Its a todo list program. Can anybody explain what happens in each step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

why this || symbol used here? what happens to notes please explain

```
      var notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) ||  

              {"shopping list": ""};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It defines a default value to notes.
In other word we could say "Notes is {"shopping list": ""} if Json.parse is null"

Take a look at the accepted answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696642/setting-a-default-variable-value-in-a-function/16696682).

Hope it may helps you

Comment: yeah got it dfayet thanks.