# Condense this javascript using ternary operators

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, ternary

I am looking to assign rlPrice to either 0 (if undefined) or to the defined price which would be available. This below will do it ok.

```
if($('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price") == undefined){
    rlPrice = 0;
else{
    rlPrice = $('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price");
}
```

However is there a way to do it with ternary operators?

```
rlPrice = $('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price") OR 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastest way is to use coalescing operator:

```
rlPrice = $('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price") || 0;
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/1409881)

Comment: +1 `null coalescing` this is the opt word.  Thanks for letting me know this and I like this clean approach.

Comment: Note that the `||` js operator is not perfectly equal to c#'s `??`, see clarifications on the linked page

Comment: @user1671639 you mean `apt` word??

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator has the form

```
d = a ? b : c;
```

Effectively, it means if `a` is true, then assign `b` to `d`, otherwise assign `c` to `d`.

So, replacing the real expressions in the above statement:

```
rlPrice = $('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price") == undefined?0:$('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **`if..else`** statement is precised using the **`?:`** opertor.

```
rlPrice = $('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price") == undefined 
           ? 0 
           : $('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price");
```