# array push with OR operand

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

There's a code written in javascript I have to re-use/modify and there's a line I don't understand:

```
var source, data = [];        
for (var id in this.target.target.layerSources) {
    source = this.target.target.layerSources[id];
    data.push([id, source.title || id, source.url]); //I don't understand this line
}
```

I looked it up but I don't find any example/explanation.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: It's a null coalescing operator.

[Here's an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost right, it means if `source.title` is **falsy**, it will take the variable `id` instead.

Falsy values are :

```
false
''
0
null
undefined
NaN
```

Comment: Ohhh alright. I assumed "id, source.title" and "id, source.url" were the two sides of the OR but it's just source.title and id. It makes so much more sense. Thanks mate.