# Javascript Question Mark & Double Pipes

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, operators

I am new to javascript and so far it is my understanding that:

`?` & `:` is used for "if true, do this, if false do this"

However, I am having a little more trouble with `||`. From my browsing it seems something like "if the first one is true do that, otherwise do this"

I am trying to figure out the following code - any suggestions on what they mean together in this context?:

```
function isSubset(series, description){
    var subset = true;
    var exactMatch = true;
    demoCodes = ['age', 'edu', 'race', 'sex'];
    for (var i = 0; i < demoCodes.length; i++){
        var demoCode = demoCodes[i];
        subset = (subset) ? (description[demoCode] == 0 || description[demoCode] == series[demoCode]) : false;
        exactMatch = (exactMatch) ? description[demoCode] == series[demoCode] : false;
    }
    return {subset: subset, exactMatch: exactMatch};
}
```

Thanks! Cheers

Comment: MDN Documentation for [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: `    if (subset) {
        if (description[demoCode] == 0) {
            subset = true;
        } else {
            subset = (description[demoCode] == series[demoCode]);
        }
    } else {
        subset = false;
    }`

Comment: You might find this [analysis of `||` vs `&&` vs `??`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143185/8910547) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` means "or". The left side of the `||` is evaluated first. If it resolves to true, then the expression resolves to true. If, on the other hand, the left side of the `||` operator resolves to false, then the right side will be evaluated and returned.

Example 1:

```
1 == 1 || 1 == 0
```

Will evaluate to true, since the left side of the || operator is true.

Example 2:

```
1 == 2 || 1 == 1
```

The left side resolves to false, so the right side is evaluated and returned. In this case, 1==1 so the whole expression (`1 == 2 || 1 == 1`) resolves to true.

Example 3:

```
1 == 2 || 1 == 3
```

The left side resolves to false, so the right side is evaluated and returned. In this case, 1 does not equal 3, so the whole expression (`1 == 2 || 1 == 3`) resolves to false.

To put it more simply, **if either of the expressions** "held together" by the || operator are true, then the expression will return true. Otherwise, it will return false.

Comment: ah, while your original answer made sense, the added edit with the bold clarification really helped me understand the logic in this function. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
subset = (subset) ? (description[demoCode] == 0 || description[demoCode] == series[demoCode]) : false;
```

is equal to

```
if(subset){
  subset = (description[demoCode] == 0 || description[demoCode] == series[demoCode);
}
else { subset = false; }
```

The `||` is an or operator here and evaluates to `true` or `false`