# unknown Javascript syntax meaning

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure about the meaning of this expression :

```
var Ajax = Ajax || {};
```

I think its create a new object if not exists, but I 'm not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Question Mark & Double Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636653/javascript-question-mark-double-pipes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Comment: You are correct, it creates a new Ajax object if it does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It assigns `{}` to `Ajax` if `Ajax` doesn't yet exist, else it `Ajax` keeps its value.