# JavaScript variable with pipeline

Tags: javascript

I have found a code in javascript which is creating an object. 
But I have clearly no idea what exactly the below code does.

```
var a = a || {};
```

An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/

Comment: `||` is the short-circuit OR. The code will check if a is true.. if not then a is assigned an empty object.

Answer (score 2):

The first step here is to understand that it really becomes this:

```
var a;
a = a || {};
```

...and that `var a` is a no-op if the `a` variable has already been declared previously in the current scope.

So the first part (`var a`) makes sure `a` exists as a variable if it doesn't already.

The second part then says: If `a` has a "truthy" value, keep it (don't change it). If it has a "falsey" value, assign `{}` to `a`.

The "falsey" values are `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, and of course, `false`. Truthy values are all others.

This works because of [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` (logical OR) operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) which, unlike some other languages, does not always result in `true` or `false`; instead, it evaluates the left-hand operand and, if that's truthy, takes that value as its result; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and uses that as its result.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the double-pipe like a logical *OR*.

```
var a = a OR { };
```

which pretty much means, if `a` has a Javascript truthy value, (re) assign `a` to `a`, otherwise assign a new object reference.

Answer (score 0):

It sets as the value of the variable `a` either:

- a copy of the current value of `a` if `a` exists and is a primitive type
- a reference to the current value of `a` if `a` exists and is a complex type
- a new object if `a` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

if `a` is `undefined` or `false` set `a = {}`

Answer (score 0):

Its like ordinary if condition(seems ternary operator) checking boolean and assigning values