# Is there a way to add ++ to a variable that is sometimes null?

Tags: javascript

I loop through an array like this:

```
_.each(user.groupings, function(grouping){
    conversions[i][grouping]++;
  })
}
```

Sometimes, `conversions[i][grouping]` is already set, sometimes it isn't. When it isn't, it won't be set to one, as desired, but rather NaN. I know I could do:

```
_.each(user.groupings, function(grouping){
   if(conversions[i][grouping]){
     conversions[i][grouping]++;
    }
    else{
       conversions[i][grouping] = 1
    }
  })
}
```

But is there a shorthand?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
_.each(user.groupings, function(grouping){
    conversions[i][grouping] = (conversions[i][grouping] || 0) + 1;
  })
}
```

This works something like the C# null coalescing operator:

[Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

My preferred syntax would be:

```
conversions[i][grouping] = conversions[i][grouping] ? conversions[i][grouping] + 1 : 1;
```

I think that is more readable than the || options but I guess that's personal preference.  If you're just after the least possible code this would work:

```
conversions[i][grouping] = ++conversions[i][grouping] || 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
conversion[i][grouping] = (conversion[i][grouping] || 0) + 1;
```

This code:

```
(conversion[i][grouping] || 0)
```

...will result in the value from the array if it's "truthy," or `0` if the value from the array is "falsey" (because of the way JavaScript's `||` operator words). The falsey values are `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, and of course, `false`; the truthy values are everything else. So if `conversion[i][grouping]` may be `undefined` or `null` and you want it to end up being `1` after the increment, we use the `||` to turn that into `0` before adding `1` to it and assigning the result back to the entry.