# What is the meaning of these statements || {} in this javascript code

Tags: javascript, or-operator

I'm just getting going in javascript and am reading up on the module pattern.

I have been looking at this page: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html and cannot work out what the || {} statements mean.

There are quite a few places where this code is written: (UTIL || {}));

Can anyone explain what these statements mean and what they are doing?

I assume that || means OR - but am not too certain in this context.

Here is the code from the conclusion of the article. The second and the penultimate lines are examples of the code that has me puzzled.

```
var UTIL = (function (parent, $) {
var my = parent.ajax = parent.ajax || {};

my.get = function (url, params, callback) {
    // ok, so I'm cheating a bit :)
    return $.getJSON(url, params, callback);
};

// etc...

return parent;
}(UTIL || {}, jQuery));
```

Comment: As in my answer, It makes sure the UTIL Object is not re-created everytime. If you for example would wrap this in a function you could require the load of the function which in some cases uses a lot of cpu, but avoid loading it anew when requested again.

Comment: Thanks for all of the helpful answers. I understand this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is used to define a variable if it is not set.
You can do this to ensure there is a value set!

for example:

```
function iHaveParameters(param1, param2) {
   param1 = param1 || {} //empty object
   param2 = param2 || "This should be a string"
}
```

And of course as noted, it will only invoke the second value when the first variable is null.

And in your case it is actually only setting the variable when it's not set, meaning if you include the script 3000 times, the variable will only still be defined once avoiding CPU. This way you could require the loading of a function for example

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, it's an empty JavaScript object.

What's not so obvious I guess is *why* you would do that.  A common reason is to make your code safe if the object happens to be `null` or `undefined`.  Consider the example where you are passed an object and want to access an attribute of it:

```
function myFunc(obj) {
    console.log(obj.name);
}
```

That's fine, unless `obj` is `undefined`, in which case your code will crash.

A safer way is often:

```
function myFunc(obj) {
    console.log((obj || {}).name);
}
```

Now if `obj` is `undefined` then a new empty object is created instead.  Getting the `.name` of that is safe and will simply return `undefined`.

This is obviously an over-simplified example, but the technique is widely used to make code shorter and easier to read (less tests and branches than putting `if` statements everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

It means: if the object before `||` is null, use a new empty object `{}` instead.

Read more about the operator here: [Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

{} is a short way of declaring an empty object, the same way as using [] do declare an empty array.

`var my = parent.ajax = parent.ajax || {};` means that if the object `parent.ajax` exist then set it as the value. If not, set an empty object instead.