# Javascript: If the value doesn't exist, don't output the line

Tags: javascript

N00b here! I have addresses where each part needs to be on a separate line. But if there's nothing in the Address line_2 or Address line_3, then don't insert a line break. How do I go about doing this?

My javascript:

```
var html = "<b>" +first +"\xa0" +last +"</b> <br/>" + line_1 +"<br/>" 
+ line_2 +"<br/>"
+ line_3 +"<br/>" 
+ city +"\xa0" + state +"\xa0" +zipcode;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You already answered it yourself: "But **IF**"

Comment: see question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(line_2 ? line_2 +"<br/>" : "")` which only adds the line_2 if defined and not null or else adds an empty string.

```
var html = "<b>" +first +"\xa0" +last +"</b> <br/>" + line_1 +"<br/>"
+ (line_2 ? line_2 +"<br/>" : "")
+ (line_3 ? line_3 +"<br/>" : "")
+ city +"\xa0" + state +"\xa0" +zipcode;

console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator, it is a condensed if where

```
var result = (if this is true) ? 'return this' : 'if not return this';
```

In your case, something like this

```
var html = "abc" + (line_2 == '' ? '' : line_2 + '<br>') + "xyz";
```

Comment: Please explain your answers. If OP doesn't know about an if statement, a ternary condition is mighty advanced work.

Comment: This is indeed the case, Sterling. I'm very very new to javascript.