# Null Conditional Operators

Tags: javascript

C# 6.0 has just been released and has a new nice little feature that I'd really like to use in JavaScript. They're called [Null-conditional operators](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators). These use a `?.` or `?[]` syntax.

What these do is essentially allow you to check that the object you've got isn't `null`, before trying to access a property. If the object is `null`, then you'll get `null` as the result of your property access instead.

```
int? length = customers?.Length;
```

So here `int` can be null, and will take that value if `customers` is null. What is even better is that you can chain these:

```
int? length = customers?.orders?.Length;
```

I don't believe we can do this in JavaScript, but I'm wondering what's the neatest way of doing something similar. Generally I find chaining `if` blocks difficult to read:

```
var length = null;
if(customers && customers.orders) {
    length = customers.orders.length;
}
```

Comment: Let's rewrite some JavaScript engines!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript

Comment: You could `var length = customers && customers.orders && customers.orders.length`;

Comment: Aactually, jnyranger might be on to something. Write a pre processing script to extend the js syntax.

Comment: Maybe lodash's [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs#get) can help: `var customer = null, length = _.get(customer, "orders.length", null); // length -> null` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxrrckxg/)

Comment: @NickBailey I'm actually quite liking that idea too come to think of it, other answers are so verbose...

Comment: This feature might come in ES2016 or ES2017. There have been several discussions about this but no consensus yet afaik. Also, you don't have to write a JS engine, you can write a [Babel](https://babeljs.io) plugin.

Comment: @FelixKling: Good shout, I've been meaning to look at Babel, writing a plug-in might be quite fun. That might be worth adding as an answer

Comment: This is the latest discussion is found: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/existential-operator-null-propagation-operator . But I don't think there is a proposal yet.

Comment: While this is framework-specific and of trivial interest, [Angular2 does provide a template-level `?.`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35073334/114900)

Comment: It exists in 2020!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Called "[optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)", it's currently a [TC39 proposal in Stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining). A [Babel plugin](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.0.0-alpha.15) however is already available in v7.

Example usage:

```
const obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 42,
    },
  },
};

const baz = obj?.foo?.bar?.baz; // 42

const safe = obj?.qux?.baz; // undefined
```

Comment: It's almost there: [available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Browser_compatibility) in Chrome 80 and Firefox 74, Safari is lagging behind.

Answer (score 16):

Js logical operators return not `true` or `false`, but `truly` or `falsy` value itself. For example in expression `x && y`, if `x` is falsy, then it will be returned, otherwise `y` will be returned. So the truth table for operator is correct.

In your case you could use expression `customers && customers.orders && customers.orders.Length` to get `length` value or the first `falsy` one.

Also you can do some magic like `((customers || {}).orders || {}).length`
(Personally, I don't like this syntax and possible garbage collection pressure as well)

Or even use `maybe` monad.

```
function Option(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.hasValue = !!value;
}

Option.prototype.map = function(s) {
    return this.hasValue
        ? new Option(this.value[s])
        : this;
}

Option.prototype.valueOrNull = function() {
    return this.hasValue ? this.value : null;
}

var length = 
    new Option(customers)
        .map("orders")
        .map("length")
        .valueOrNull();
```

It's longer than all the previous approaches, but clearly shows your intentions without any magic behind.

Comment: Thanks - I could, but what I'd like to try and do is get to something that's much less verbose.

Comment: @Ian, maybe, there is smth in that really long [list](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) with `null-coalesce` operator and js backward compatibility. I've hoped for type script, but there is not support yet. coffee script has `elvis-operator`, but its syntax and paradigm is too different from js.

Comment: @Ian, added one more option in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that update is where my head was going when I was thinking about the problem. It's the most concise, it's just hard to read - which is where I wondered about any utilities that already existed or other automagical approaches.

Comment: I think that last should be `((customers || {}).orders || []).length` (an empty array after the last `||`).

Comment: @poke it haven't been specified that orders is `array`, so :)

Comment: @Ian, what about functional approach? longer, but clearer as for me. updated answer one more time (the last)

Comment: @Vladislav heh, fair enough ;P

Comment: @poke btw [].length will return 0, and you wont be able to distinguish it from empty orders collection. While ({}).length will propagate undefined as required and it's a correct one, I think.

Comment: What is "maybe monad"? Is that an "Else Heart.Break()" reference I'm not getting?

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to improve code readability (depending on your needs):

1. You already use [babeljs](/questions/tagged/babeljs) (v7 or above) and you use ["Optional Chaining" babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) (finished proposal) (or just [preset-stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-3)):

   ```
   const length = customers?.orders?.Length;

   // With default value (otherwise it will be `undefined`):
   const length = customers?.orders?.Length || defaultLength;

   // File: .babelrc
   { "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"] }
   ```
2. You already use [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) (v3.7 or greater): Use the [`lodash.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) method:

   ```
   var length = _.get(customers, 'orders.length');

   // With default value (otherwise it will be `undefined`):
   var length = _.get(customers, 'orders.length', defaultLength);
   ```
3. Plain javascript:

   ```
   var length = customers && customers.orders && customers.orders.length;

   // With default value (otherwise it may be whatever falsy value "customers" or "customers.orders" might have):
   var length = (customers
       && customers.orders
       && customers.orders.length) || defaultLength;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty version that works.

```
String.prototype.nullSafe = function() {
    return eval('var x='+this.replace(/\?/g,';if(x)x=x')+';x');
};
```

Example usage:

```
var obj = { 
    Jim: 1,
    Bob: { "1": "B", "2": "o", "3": "b" },
    Joe: [ 1, 2, 3, { a: 20 } ]
};

 obj.Joe[3].a                 // 20    
"obj.Joe[3]?.a".nullSafe()    // 20

 obj.Joe[4].a                 // Error: Can't read 'a' from undefined
"obj.Joe[4].a".nullSafe()     // Error: Can't read 'a' from undefined
"obj.Joe[4]?.a".nullSafe()    // undefined

 obj.Jack[3].a.b              // Error: Can't read '3' from undefined
"obj.Jack[3].a.b".nullSafe()  // Error: Can't read '3' from undefined
"obj.Jack?[3].a.b".nullSafe() // undefined
```