# Angular 2 template tags say object is undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Dealing with strange issue in Angular 2.

If you look in the component below, the service returns a parsed object – for instance I can `console.log` it. You can see the output pasted as a comment. Whenever I try to use said object in the view, I get an error: `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subject' of undefined in [{{theData.subject}} in SubjectHomeComponent@2:27]`.

This doesn't make sense to me as I can see the object in console just fine. Running `typeof` also returns that it's an object.

**Component Code**

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/core'
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common'
import {SubjectService} from "../../services/subject/SubjectService.ts";
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
import { Response } from 'angular2/http'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {RouteParams} from "angular2/router";


@Component({
    selector: 'subjectHomeComponent',
    providers: [SubjectService]
})

@View({
    template: `
        Hello World <span>{{theData.subject}}</span>
    `
})

export class SubjectHomeComponent{
    constructor(subjectService: SubjectService, params: RouteParams){
        this.id = params.get('id')

        subjectService.getSubjectCardsAndNotes(this.id)
            .subscribe((res: Response) => {
                this.theData = res
                console.log(res) //returns {"subject":{"id":1,"name":"Spanish","created_at":"2016-01-23T06:54:50.321Z","updated_at":"2016-01-23T06:54:50.321Z"},"subject_id":1,"notes":[{"id":1,"title":"first note","body":"here i am!","created_at":"2016-01-27T03:10:09.238Z","updated_at":"2016-01-27T03:10:09.238Z","subject_id":1},{"id":2,"title":"first_note","body":"hello _buddy_","created_at":"2016-01-28T20:45:36.044Z","updated_at":"2016-01-28T20:45:36.044Z","subject_id":1}]}

            });
    }
}
```

**Service Code (Which I don't think is relevant but you never know)**

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Response} from "angular2/http";
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SubjectService{
    constructor(public http: Http){

    }

   getSubject(){
      return this.http.request('/subjects.json')
          .map((response) => response.json())
    }
    getSubjectCardsAndNotes(id){
        return this.http.request(`subjects/${id}/subject_cards_and_notes.json`)
            .map((response) => response.json())
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833358/angular-2-typeerror-l-thing0-is-undefined-in-thing-title-in-appcomponent/34833436#34833436

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try: `{{theData?.subject}}` or `<span *ngIf="theData">{{theData.subject}}</span>`.

The why is in lots of duplicated questions:

[Angular 2: TypeError: l_thing0 is undefined in [{{thing.title}} in AppComponent@4:44]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833358/angular-2-typeerror-l-thing0-is-undefined-in-thing-title-in-appcomponent/34833436#34833436)