# Angular 4 Get json from Http and display to Dom

Tags: angular, typescript

I am missing something on interpolation i think. 
i use http.get for my service to get data

post.service code :

```
getPosts() {return this._http.get(this._Url + 'events').map((_response: Response) => {
  const data = _response.json()
  return _response.json();
});
```

on my component i run the following code to pass the response to the res array 
component code :

```
getdata(){this._postService.getPosts()
  .subscribe(
  posts => {
    posts.forEach(posts => {
      this.res.push(
        new event(
          posts.field_event_title[0].value,
          posts.field_event_price[0].value,
          "test loc"
        )
      )

    });


  }
  ,
  (error) => console.log(error, "error from observable")
  );
  console.log(this.res, "res after subs")
}
```

Html Code:

```
<div  class="row" *ngFor="let post of res">
  Title: {{post.title}} <br>
  Price: {{post.price}} <br>
  Location:{{post.location}}
</div>
```

My issue is that with *ngFor i get my data displayed. but i want to read only 1 post ex. res[0].title. When i am using in html {{ res[0].title }}  i get the error "cannot read property "title " of undefined. Any help on that !? in the end what i want is to be able to use the array res to display data in the dom

Comment: Because your array starts empty, you need to surround it with a `*ngIf="res.length > 0"`

Comment: Try `res[0]?.title` This is async issue, so use safe navigation operator :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 template tags say object is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073267/angular-2-template-tags-say-object-is-undefined)

Comment: Or do what AJT_82 said, or even use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safe navigation operator was my issue as AJT_82 said. Thanks guys !