# parsing json data into objects with type script

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My json data:

```js
{
  "status": "OK",
  "data": {
    "id": 3,
    "initials": "mci",
    "nom": "chabli",
    "prenom": "mohammed Yassin",
    "password": "m1ltRoJZRS",
    "username": "yassine.chabli@edu.umi.ac.ma",
    "photo": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": [{
        "id": 2,
        "roleName": "DP",
        "topSupression": false,
        "lesGrilles": [{
            "id": 2,
            "affecte": true,
            "privilege": {
              "id": 1,
              "actionName": "AjouterAVV"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "affecte": true,
            "privilege": {
              "id": 2,
              "actionName": "ModifierAVV"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "roleName": "CP",
        "topSupression": false,
        "lesGrilles": [{
            "id": 4,
            "affecte": true,
            "privilege": {
              "id": 1,
              "actionName": "AjouterAVV"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "affecte": true,
            "privilege": {
              "id": 2,
              "actionName": "ModifierAVV"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "departement": {
      "id": 1,
      "libelle": "Software",
      "topSupression": false,
      "area": {
        "id": 1,
        "libelle": "Maroc",
        "topSupression": false
      }
    }
  },
  "error": null
}
```

I get this data successfully in my angular component like this:

```
import {AfterContentInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service' ;
import {User} from '../classes/user' ;
import {Departement} from '../classes/departement';
import {Region} from '../classes/region';
import {Role} from '../classes/role';
import {Grille} from '../classes/grille';
import {Privilege} from '../classes/privilege';
@Component({
  selector: 'rb-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit  {
  user: User = new User() ;
  dept: Departement = new Departement();
  area: Region = new Region();
  roles: Role[] ;
  grilles: Grille[];
  privilege: Privilege
  status: string ;
  error: string;
  constructor(public _us: UserService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._us.getOneUser().subscribe(
      data => (this.user = data.data, this.status = data.status, this.error = data.error , this.dept = this.user.departement,
        this.area = this.dept.area , this.roles = this.user.roles),
      error => alert(error),
      () => console.log(this.roles)
    );
  }
}
```

In my HTML view I try to show some attribute like `{{user.username }}` it works. 
But when I try to show like `user.roles[0].id` or something like that I have some error in the console:

> the property id is undefined

While when I'm logging the user variable in the console, I can see that the property id of my roles array exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 template tags say object is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073267/angular-2-template-tags-say-object-is-undefined)

Comment: This is an async issue... you can use the safe navigation operator: `user?.roles[0]?.id` or wrap it inside *ngIf. Check the duplicate :)