# Angular cannot read property of undefined in component/form

Tags: angular

I am trying to get UPDATE to work from my CRUD API.  I know the issue is either in the form or component for UPDATE, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**Form HTML**

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateReminder(form.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nameField">Name:</label>
    <input name="nameField" class="form-control" [ngModel]="reminders.name">
    <br />
    <label for="occasionField">Occasion:</label>
    <input name="occasionField" class="form-control" 
[ngModel]="reminders.occasion">
 </div>
 <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

**Form Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ReminderService } from '../providers/reminder.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.css'],
  providers: [ReminderService]

})
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private reminderService:ReminderService) {}

 reminderList = null;
 @Input() reminders; 


ngOnInit() {}   


updateReminder(obj:any):void {
 this.reminders.name = obj.nameField;
 this.reminders.occasion = obj.occasionField;
 this.reminderService.updateReminder(this.reminders._id, this.reminders)
  .subscribe((result) =>{
    location.reload();
 })
}
```

**App Component HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<app-intro title="{{title}}"></app-intro>
<app-form ></app-form>
<app-results *ngFor='let reminder of reminderList' [reminders]="reminder">
</app-results>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**App Component (There are no routers)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ReminderService } from './providers/reminder.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ReminderService]
})
export class AppComponent {

 title = 'The Amazing Reminder App';

  constructor(private reminderService:ReminderService) {}

  reminderList = null;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.reminderService.listReminders().subscribe((reminders)=>{
        this.reminderList = reminders;
    });
 } 
}
```

The error is in the HTML:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
<input name="nameField" class="form-control" [ngModel]="reminders.name">
```

Comment: In which row the error occurres?

Comment: Sorry, in the HTML.  <input name="nameField" class="form-control" [ngModel]="reminders.name">  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that as an Input variable, the `reminders` object is initially undefined until angular has finished initializing the component. See this line right here.

```
@Input() reminders;
```

The html part however does not wait to render and therefore tries to use this variable very early on.

```
<input name="nameField" class="form-control" [ngModel]="reminders.name">
```

So when it tries to resolve the model before the input variable is set during the initialization process, it hits an undefined variable and tries to find a `name` field in it, which of course does not exist yet.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem.

1. give the `reminders` object a default value, maybe even an empty object. I personally think this way you sacrifice memory usage to prevent errors, which seems kind of unclean
2. use the elvis operator as a null check in your html:  `[ngModel]="reminders?.name"`. You have to do this in every field that tries to access a field of the reminders object, which can be a lot of code depending on your form
3. only render the form when the reminders object is finally set. This can easily be done with a simple `*ngIf` on the surrounding div or form: `<div class="form-group" *ngIf="reminders">`

This is probably a personal choice but for me the last option seems to be the cleanest. There's no reason to render your view before the needed values are existing and then rerender it when they are set.

There are more questions around this topic, for example you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073267/angular-2-template-tags-say-object-is-undefined) one right here.

Hope this helps.

---

### EDIT

So I rechecked your code and while your `updateReminder` function is the form submit, I guess this is a pure update form. In this case, I'd say that option 3 should be working fine. Angular does some neat change detection and rerendering, so you should probably first check out if the input variable is set correctly. If yes, angular should do the rest and rerender the `*ngIf` part the moment it realizes that the object exists now.

Before we check the input variable it is always helpful to understand how angular handles input variables, which in the end boils down to the so called *Lifecycle Hooks*. One special hook is the `ngOnInit()` hook. Here's what angular's [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) says about the hook:

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties

What this basically means is that variables transported to the component as an `@Input` are *not* set when the component is created (constructor code), but only after it was initialized. This results in some execution delay and in the end to the error you stated above.

To check out if the input variable was set correctly, we can just log it to the console inside `ngOnInit()`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.reminders);
}
```

As a comparision, if you do this in the constructor, you will see that it is still empty at this point.

```
constructor(private reminderService:ReminderService) {
  // should be undefined at this point
  console.log(this.reminders);
}
```

So if the reminders variable is logged from the `ngOnInit`, the `*ngIf` approach should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for such a well thought out answer.  That actually helps a lot in terms of the "why".  I opted for #3, but when I put in the *ngIf, the form disappears.  I'm guessing I need to put something in ngInit it instantiate the component?

Comment: I see your point. This of course comes down to where your reminders object comes from. Because it is noted with `@Input` I assumed the object comes from outside your component as a fully created object. If this is not the case, for example if the form is just used to create a completely new object and not to update an existing one, I'd instantiate the object with a completely fresh empty object right on the declaration (solution 1). This is also recommended when it is used to handle both fresh creation and update of an existing object, because it is kind of a fall back when nothing exists yet.

Comment: as solution 1 seems to do the trick here, I just guess you don't input the reminders variable at all. Just check if you actually need the @Input notation. Just remember that when you input a variable, it overrites the existing one. So if you initialize the object with an empty state but input an undefined object, I bet the error will still occur, just in a later lifecycle hook.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide more detail about what is going on and how to find possible problems

Comment: I went back and consoled the ngOnInit and found the reminders object is undefined which does explain a lot.  What I'm not sure of, however, is how to set it up in the component so it loads.  reminders:reminders{}  isn't right.  Sorry, I'm still pretty new.

Comment: don't worry dude, all good. Can you update your question and post the html code where you include your `<app-results></app-results>`? Maybe even post the code where you get load or create the reminders object in the parent. Or maybe there is no parent and you're creating the component through a direct router link, then we have to load the object to update inside the `ResultsComponent`, but as far as it looks now using the @Input() notation, I guess it should come from a parent component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170574/discussion-between-benedikt-schmidt-and-megler).