# Is there a JS equivalent for C# "?." operator?

Tags: javascript, c#, syntactic-sugar

What I'm looking for is actually a shortcut for JS
    `obj.fn && obj.fn();`
code. One of the reasons for that is sometimes the `obj.fn` part might be quite long.

C# uses the [Null Conditional Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) for that: `obj?.fn()`

Comment: Is it the null coalescing operator you are talking about? It's already there... `?:`

Comment: Lemme know if this is not a dupe of that question... `:)`

Comment: No, actually there's no such operator available in JavaScript, but it's planned for a future version: https://tc39.github.io/proposal-optional-chaining/

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman That's not a duplicate. `?.` is not the same as `??` which is the acutal _null coalescing_ operator for C#

Comment: Seems like they are thinking about to implement this functionality but at date of March 2018 they still didn't include this.
https://www.beyondjava.net/elvis-operator-aka-safe-navigation-javascript-typescript

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Sorry guys... Reopened. `:)`

Comment: So there's a Babel plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538150/201303

Answer (score -2):

> One of the reasons for that is sometimes the obj.fn part might be quite long.

```
var a = obj.fn;
a && a();
```

Now you only use the long part once. That's likely the closest you'll get in javascript.

Comment: If you're going to do that, you probably need to bind the function back to `obj`.