# Filter list with substring javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var ctr;
var lst = ["", "xml", "w1", "w2"];
var ids = [];
ctr = 0;
for (y = 0; y < lst.length; y++) {
    if (lst[y].substring(0, 1) === "w") {
        ids[y] = lst[y];
        ctr = ctr + 1;
    }
}
console.log([ids, ctr]);
```

OUTPUT: `[[undefined, undefined, 'w1','w2'], 2]`
EXPECTED OUTPUT: `[['w1','w2'],2]`

What am I doing wrong? The counter returned the number I have expected but why am i getting 2 undefined in my list? Why is this happening?

Comment: What you are actually getting is `[[,,'w1','w2'], 2]`, i.e. there are no members at indexes 0 and 1. Console developers seem to have forgotten how to write elisions (or rely on *toString* when perhaps they should not)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `ids.push(lst[y]);` instead of `ids[y] = lst[y];`, otherwise you will be assigning values to the `ids` array at random indexes - ie missing some index values.

In your code the values are assigned at indexes 2 and 3 missing indexes 0 and 1 causing the said output, it is because you are not assigning values to `ids` in all iterations - you are skipping some iterations based on the condition

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a filter to get the items you want and maybe use the output array length to know how many items you have after filtering the original array.

```
var newArr = ["", "xml", "w1", "w2"].filter(function(x) {
  x.substring(0, 1) === 'w');
};

console.log([newArr, newArr.length]);    // [["w1", "w2"], 2]
```

Comment: probably 1 without arrow function will be better

Answer (score 2):

```
var lst = ["", "xml", "w1", "w2"];

var result = lst.reduce(function (x, y) {
  if (y.substring(0, 1) === 'w') {
    x[0] || (x[0] = []);
    x[0].push(y);
    x[1]++ || (x[1] = 1);
  }
  return x;
}, []);

console.log(result) // [["w1","w2"],2]
```

The result will be same as required, interesting to note here i use null coalescing notation `||` [more info about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)

Suggested by `@FelixKing` changing the accumulator

```
lst.reduce(function (x, y) {
  if (y.substring(0, 1) === 'w') {
    x[0].push(y);
    x[1]++;
  }
  return x;
}, [[], 0]);
```

Comment: If you'd pass `[[], 0]` as initial accumulator you don't have to check for `undefined` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using existing `js` , try substituting `ctr` for `y` inside `if` statement

```js
var ctr;
var lst = ["", "xml", "w1", "w2"];
var ids = [];
ctr = 0;
for (y = 0; y < lst.length; y++) {
  if (lst[y].substring(0, 1) === "w") {
    ids[ctr] = lst[y];
    ctr = ctr + 1;
  } 
}

console.log([ids, ctr]);
```

alternatively , using `Array.prototype.toString()` , `String.prototype.match()`

```js
var lst = ["", "xml", "w1", "w2"]
, ids = lst.toString().match(/w./g);
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: That would produce the same unwanted output, albeit now the array literally contains undefined.

Comment: Why don't just filter the original array `lst`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a different approach, using reduce will also work:

```
var res = lst.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal){
    if (curVal.substring(0, 1) === "w") {
        prevVal[0].push(curVal);
        prevVal[1] = prevVal[1] + 1;
    }
    return prevVal;
}, [[], 0]);

console.log(res); //--> [['w1', 'w2'], 2]
```

I recommend it simply because avoiding for loops whenever possible makes for much more maintainable code, especially in Javascript where the vars used in the for loop condition itself are still members of the parent scope (i.e. they're accessible throughout the entire containing function, with a value of undefined given to them until the initialization value is given in the for loop).

Also, it prevents you from having to juggle index values in your head, and instead concentrate on what the loop is actually doing.

*(My above example definitely could be cleaner, but it should give you an idea)*

Comment: Not sure that avoiding for loops makes any difference to maintainability, zillions of lines of javascript were written before Array iterators became available. Loops are certainly much faster. ;-)

Comment: It's more of a rule of thumb. However, I think it's almost always true if:
a) you have 1 or more nested loops; 
b) you're using callbacks, streams, promises, &/or control flow libraries (e.g. async, q); or
c) you're doing NodeJS (all of 'b' + generators, 'nextTick', etc.).
In the latter 2, for-loops produce a lot of hard-to-predict behaviour, & the iterator value can't be relied on. 

Simple example: if you surround a process.nextTick call with a for loop, all references to the iterator var in the nextTick callback will return the final iterator value (you'll get the final val multiple times).

Comment: And then came *let*. ;-) Not big on server–side JS, thanks for the heads–up.