# Is there a slick way to do undefined coalescence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, null-coalescing-operator

I'm looking for a way to do undefined coalescing in javascript with booleans. I'm used to doing the following, for, say, positive integers:

```
var x = i1 || i2 || i3 || i4;
```

This is a 'slick' way, but is not what I'm after. I'm looking for the equivalent of `??` in C#.

```
var b1 = undefined;
var b2 = null;
var b3 = false;
var b4 = true;
var x = b1 || b2 || b3 || b4; //x == true (b4)
```

However, I want the above to 'stop' on false (coalesce on undefined or null, but NOT false). The application I'm doing this for is similar to the following:

```
var threshold = argv[2] ?? process.env.threshold ?? config.threshold ?? 0.3;
var verbose = isTrue(argv[3] ?? process.env.verbose ?? config.verbose ?? false);
```

I'm looking for a *slick* way do to this, similar to the `||` operator, not:

```
var verbose = false;
if (config.verbose !== undefined && config.verbose !== null) verbose = isTrue(config.verbose);
if (process.env.verbose !== undefined && process.env.verbose !== null) verbose = isTrue(process.env.verbose);
if (argv[3] !== undefined && argv[3] !== null) verbose = isTrue(argv[3]);
```

Similarly, I'd want a '0' threshold to be accepted for the threshold, and any undefined or null values skipped.

Answer (score 5):

The slickest way (without adding extra functions) that I can think of is:

```
var x = [b1, b2, b3, b4].find(x => x !== null && x !== undefined);
```

If this is to be used over and over, define a function that does all the work for you:

```
function coalesce() {
    return [].find.call(arguments, x => x !== null && x !== undefined);
}

var x = coalesce(b1, b2, b3, b4);
```

NB: ES2015 syntax used and functionality used above!  It'd be trivial to rewrite in "old" syntax and shim the `Array.prototype.any` function for older browsers.

Also note that without native support for a coalescing operator that *all* of the parameters above will be evaluated - you lose the advantage of the short circuiting of `||` or `??` wherein the right hand expression isn't evaluated if the left hand expression is returned.

Comment: Hmm, if adding functions is the only way to go, can I define my own null coalescing operator to `??`? What are my choices of symbols if not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @Ehryk you can't define your own operators in JS.  See answer update though for an improved function.

Answer (score 1):

As of December 7th, 2022:

Nullish coalescing operator (`??`) is supported by the browsers used by roughly [94% of users](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing). Polyfills for older browsers are [available](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) in popular bundlers.

The operator is also available on Node.js as of [version 14.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V14.md#update-to-v8-81)