# Convert some JS to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I wan't to translate some code from JS to C# but can't really imagine one part...

```
function getHisto(pixels) {
        var histosize = 1 << (3 * sigbits),
            histo = new Array(histosize),
            index, rval, gval, bval;
        pixels.forEach(function(pixel) {
            rval = pixel[0] >> rshift;
            gval = pixel[1] >> rshift;
            bval = pixel[2] >> rshift;
            index = getColorIndex(rval, gval, bval);
            histo[index] = (histo[index] || 0) + 1;
        });
        return histo;
    }
```

what exactly have can I expect from histo[]? I don't understand that line:

```
histo[index] = (histo[index] || 0) + 1;
```

If you need any additional information I'll try to give it.

Edit 1: I specifically meant `histo[index] || 0`

Comment: What gets you puzzled? The `histo[index] || 0` part? This just means, "if histo[index] is undefined, use zero".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify what confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
histo[index] = (histo[index] || 0) + 1;
```

is a shortcut for achieving this:

```
if (!histo[index]) { 
    histo[index] = 0; 
}
histo[index] = histo[index] + 1;
```

Which might make more sense to you.

See [this answer for comparison between the almost equivalent `??` in C# and `||` in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/1630906)

Answer (score 1):

The line `histo[index] = (histo[index] || 0) + 1;`

Is adding to the array and working out where to put it via the `current index + 1` or `0 + 1`.

Basically the or (`||`) handles the edge case of it being the first one added to `histo`.

Answer (score 1):

The square-bracket notation is the same as in C#, it's array access by index.

Take a look at [this tutorial on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288465(v=vs.71).aspx).

For example. If you have an array with two items in it:

```
// javascript
var x = ["a", "b"];

// C#
var y = string[] {"a", "b"};
```

The first item is at index `0` and the second is at index `1`. You can then access each item using the square bracket notation:

```
var first = x[0];
var second = x[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

**`||` is a [Logical-OR operator in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR)**

The equivalent to replace this in C#, would be a [`??` Null-Coalesce operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

So basically in `C#`, your line would look like this.

```
histo[index] = (histo[index] ?? 0) + 1;
```