# Using ternary operator how can i check value is from which $stateParams?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have conditional parameters on ui-router because I am using the same screen in different places in an app. I have to write logic to check which `$stateParams` value I have assigned to `paramId`. I have tried with `if` and `else`.

Is there a better approach to achieve this task?

```
$scope.challengesDTO = {
    challengeTypeLkupCode: 'RA_CHLNG_TYP_PRC'
};

var paramId = $stateParams.processId ? $stateParams.processId : $stateParams.assessmentId;

if ($stateParams.processId) {
    $scope.challengesDTO.challengeTypeLkupCode = 'RA_CHLNG_TYP_PRC'
} else if ($stateParams.assessmentId) {
    $scope.challengesDTO.challengeTypeLkupCode = 'RA_CHLNG_TYP_RSKASES'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Consider The Null-Coalescing Operator**

You should be able to replace your ternary operator with [the null coalescing operator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/557445) `||`, which essentially a logical 'OR' statement :

```
// This will set it to processId (if available), otherwise assessmentId
var paramId = $stateParams.processId || $stateParams.assessmentId;
```

**A Ternary (if you want one)**

However, if you were just worried about setting your `challengeTypeLkupCode` property, you could use the following, which would set it depending on if `processId` existed or not :

```
// Set your lookup type depending if processId exists or not
$scope.challengesDTO.challengeTypeLkupCode = ($stateParams.processId) ? 'RA_CHLNG_TYP_PRC' : 'RA_CHLNG_TYP_RSKASES';
```

For readability purposes, you may be best off just using an if statement as seen in your initial code.

Comment: is there way to check value assigned to `paramId` is`processId` or `assessmentId`?

Comment: Not without performing another comparison to explicitly see if `paramId` is equal to `processId` or `assessmentId`. This is why an if-statement may be preferred as you can perform a single comparison and perform all of your logic related to the comparison within the body of the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

For the if else condition u mentioned above u can try-

```
$scope.challengesDTO.challengeTypeLkupCode=$stateParams.processId?'RA_CHLNG_TYP_PRC':$stateParams.assessmentId?'RA_CHLNG_TYP_RSKASES':"Default value u want to give";
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part goes with a logical OR `||`

```
var paramId =  $stateParams.processId || $stateParams.assessmentId;
```

The second part is with a nested ternary operator `?:` and returns the value itself if no comparison becomes true.

```
$scope.challengesDTO.challengeTypeLkupCode = $stateParams.processId ?
    'RA_CHLNG_TYP_PRC' :
    $stateParams.assessmentId ?
        'RA_CHLNG_TYP_RSKASES' :
        $scope.challengesDTO.challengeTypeLkupCode;
```