# Null coalescing operator angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, null-coalescing-operator

What is the equivalent of null coalescing operator (??) in angular 2?

In C# we can perform this operation:

```
string str = name ?? FirstName ?? "First Name is null";
```

Comment: Fixed the OP's example to proper C#.

Answer (score 127):

Coalescing is performed via `||` operator, i.e.

```
let str:string = name || FirstName || "name is null and FirstName is null";
```

---

You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/573032) question for more details and explanations.

Comment: Or operator(||) is not same exactly with nullish coalescing. For example:
"" || "ibrahim" return "ibrahim" and
0 || "ibrahim" return "ibrahim" again. But with coalescing first operation returns "" and second returns 0. Because nullish coalescing only control whether the left-sided  value is equal null or undefined

Comment: Beware - this is not null coalescing operator as `false || true` returns `true`.

Comment: For anyone who thinks this wouldn't matter since the `name` and `FirstName` variables are most likely `strings`, consider how JavaScript and TypeScript handle empty strings. If the `name` and `FirstName` fields are empty strings it would result in `name is null and First Name is null` despite neither of them being null.

Answer (score 6):

#### In Typescript

Typescript introduced null coalescing with version `3.7`, so if you're running on `3.7` or higher you can simply write:

```
const str = name ?? firstName ?? "Name and First Name are both null";
const x = foo?.bar.baz() ?? bizz();
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing.

#### In the Angular Template

Since Angular 12 you can also use `??` in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want achieve is this:

```js
let str =
    typeof (name) !== 'undefined' && name !== null ?
        name : typeof (FirstName ) === 'undefined' || FirstName  === null ?
        "First Name is null" : FirstName
```

Comment: If the `name` and `FirstName` fields are empty strings it would result in `First Name is null` despite neither of them being null.

Answer (score 0):

The operator was added in TypeScript 3.7
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing