# javascript : || double pipe operator alternative that tests undefined only

Tags: javascript, operators

Is there any shorter notation for the following test?

```
(typeof x != "undefined") ? x : y;
```

A kind of `x || y` but that operates on **undefined** only (and not **falsey values**)

Something like `??` of C#

Comment: No, there is no such operator.

Comment: Why? is it very important to shorten the code further?

Comment: || is not double pipe it is just logical "OR"

Comment: Define a function? `const foo = (x, y) => (typeof x != "undefined") ? x : y;  ... foo(x, y)`.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no shorter way to evaluate only undefined.

Comment: @mplungjan : the x || y notation is everywhere in your everyday javascript. But when people write it -most of the time- they really mean (typeof x != "undefined") ? x : y. And they get confused when it broke because of a falsey value (0 being one of those). People write x || y because they are lazy (or because they saw it elsewehere and thought they understand it while they ignore the side effects). This operator was missing in C# but was added because of popular demand. So I'm surprised there is not such notation in javascript

Comment: I have yet to be surprised by a falsy value ;) since 1995 or so (Netscape)

Answer (score 2):

In fact the question should be rephrase as is there a null coalescing operator in javascript ?

And the answer is No, not now but it should be coming soon. See proposal [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) and [implementation status here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing/issues/29).

[Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: Interesting proposals

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that undefined will never be overwritten, you can use something like `x === undefined`. This will return either `true` or `false` which you can test against.

Comment: (foo === undefined) will fail if foo is undefined. (but not if foo was set to be undefined foo = undefined)