# Is there a word that covers both Null and Undefined?

Tags: javascript, naming

I sometimes have to write code in JavaScript that handles both `null` and `undefined` the same way. For example, a function that removes from an array every item that is either `null` or `undefined`. How should I name the function?

`removeNullAndUndefined` is very long. `removeNull` is short but imprecise. Ideally I want to name it `removeX`, where `X` has the meaning "null or undefined".

Does anyone know a good word for `X`?

Comment: Depends on context. "Empty" is the general term, but if it can be a string, "empty" may also mean "a string with no characters in it", which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: So you are asking a good name for a function that would remove null and undefined value without using the term removeNullAndUndefined (I am totally fine with this by the way). I would go with : removeFalsyValues. but at this point there isn't a "good word" you have to made it up so it's kind of up to you I guess

Comment: @MaieonBrix - But `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and `false` are also falsy, and the OP seems to want to leave them alone. There is a word for this: "nullish." See my answer.

Comment: The actual subject is covered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50211024/295783

Comment: Not sure how this question can have an answer since it is really personal opinion.

Answer (score 11):

Yes: **Nullish**. For instance, in the current Stage 3 [Nullish Coalescing Operator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing).

So: `removeNullish` or similar.

Comment: I'd prefer "nully", like "truthy". (Its opposite, of course, is antNully. Go tell antNully.)

Comment: @DaveNewton - Regardless of one's preferences, "nullish" has been around for a couple of years now (at least). :-)

Comment: Unlike @DaveNewton, I prefer a,b,c,d for my variables and make sure I use i and l together so you really have to concentrate on what my code does.

Answer (score 2):

When I need to check for `null` or `undefined` I often name such function either `isNil` or `isNothing` e.g.

```js
const isNil = thing => thing === null || thing === undefined;
```

If you must adopt a naming convention I'd opt for what's quite common to see in functional programming, namely the *Maybe* monad which comes with a subtype to represent nothing: `Nothing` or `None`.

If you look at [monetjs](/questions/tagged/monetjs):

> The Maybe type is the most common way of representing nothingness (or the null type) with making the possibilities of NullPointer issues disappear.
>
> Maybe is effectively abstract and has two concrete subtypes: Some (also Just) and None (also Nothing).

Under the hood, it uses a [`isNothing`](https://github.com/monet/monet.js/blob/4269787b992b4b4b99892881aa824782e0461d0a/src/monet.js#L86) function for checking for `null` or `undefined`

In [ramda.js](/questions/tagged/ramda.js), such function is called [`isNil`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#isNil):

> Checks if the input value is null or undefined

*(Lodash has a similar method with the exact same name.)*