# An error occurs if the number field is empty

Tags: node.js, excel4node

I get an error when the field with the number is an empty value.

> Value sent to Number function of cells ["F3"] was not a number, it has
>   type of object and value of null

Can this be fixed somehow?

An example of how I fill a table with numerical values:

```
var styleNumber = wb.createStyle({
    font: {
        color: '#000000',
        size: 14,
        name: 'Times New Roman',
    },
    alignment: {
        horizontal: 'center',
        vertical: 'top'
    }
});

reports.forEach((report, index) => ws.cell(index + 3, 6).number(report._previousDataValues.code).style(styleNumber));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript has a neat trick with the `||` operator you can use

what it does is return the first value if its a truthy value and the second if it isn't

this would result in

```
reports.forEach((report, index) => ws.cell(index + 3, 6).number(report._previousDataValues.code || 0).style(styleNumber));
```

Just to write out what happens with this code:

```
previousDataValues.code = 1234
(_previousDataValues.code || 0) //returns 1234
previousDataValues.code = null
(_previousDataValues.code || 0) //returns 0
previousDataValues.code = 0
(_previousDataValues.code || 0) //returns 0
previousDataValues.code = -1234
(_previousDataValues.code || 0) //returns -1234
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/8796313

Comment: Wow,  it possible not to establish anything if a false?

Comment: @user12214130 not sure what you mean? you want a number right? so in the quick edit I did on your code it would return a 0 when the value is null

Comment: I want instead of 0 to  just an empty string

Comment: I added some examples of what happens and hope that clears it up

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same message once.
You're probably using some module like *excel4node* or  *exceljs*, right?
The problem rests on the `.number(report._previousDataValues.code)`. Here you´re considering the variable `report._previousDataValues.code` **always as a number**.
One way to prevent this kind of problem is by testing this variable and write it in the workbook in different formats. Something like this:

```
reports.forEach((report, index) => { 
if (typeof report._previousDataValues.code === 'number'){
    ws.cell(index + 3, 6).number(report._previousDataValues.code).style(styleNumber)
}else{
    ws.cell(index + 3, 6).string(report._previousDataValues.code).style(styleNumber)
}});
```