# Why does there appear to be non deterministic behavior trying to load a babel plugin in a nextjs project? Next - Babel

Tags: redux, babeljs, next.js

I have a `nextjs` app with `redux`.

When I try to use the `??` operator in my `pages/index`, it works as it should.

I then tried to load up a `redux` store with a bunch of reducers.  When I hit the `??` in a reducer file, I get this error:

`Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled (71:32):`

I also get the error in any other file: component, actions and reducers.  It is only directly in the `pages/*` that the plugin is working properly.

My app is using `next@9.1.1` and `redux@4.0.4`.  Here is my `.babelrc` file:

```
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"],
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
        [
          "styled-components",
          { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something that would override my `babel` config for certain files?  If so, what am I missing?  What else should I look at?

Comment: What do you mean by `??` operator? This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript If so, you could just use `||`. You error could mean that the first `?` is interpreted as ternary operator, and the next `?` as Typescript's "optional chaining" operator.

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing.  The optional chaining is throwing the same errors.  This is a very large project that already has lots of this syntax in it, so I don't want to have to convert anything when the js should be working as is with the proper babel plugins.