# Is it possible to shorten a ternary operator in typescript with a condition inside a for loop

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to shorten this statement to a null coalesce statement or something shorter than a ternary?

```js
for (const item of someObj.someObjArray) {
  item.startDate = item.startDate !== null ? item.startDate.split('T')[0] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&&`

```
item.startDate = item.startDate && item.startDate.split('T')[0];
```

It has nothing to do with the loop.

Comment: To expand on this, the `&&` operator will return the first argument if it is falsy (e.g. this will return `undefined` if `item.startDate` is undefined, or `''` if `item.starteDate` is `''`) and the second argument if the first is truthy.

Comment: And if you require `null` & not `undefined`, you could use the [null-coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript) to provide a default like: `item.startDate = (item.startDate && item.startDate.split('T')[0]) || null`

Comment: @Reed The original code wouldn't work for most other falsey values, so I think it's a reasonable assumption that the value is either `null` or an ISO datetime string.

Comment: do you know why tslint warns me when I use &= instead of && in your answer. I know I can mute the warning, but is it the same as &&?

Comment: `x &= y` is the same as `x = x & y`. `&` is the bit-wise AND operator, not boolean AND.

Comment: oh ok, do you know why I received an Angular error with the first answer above using ?.

Comment: It's a very new JavaScript feature, Angular may not know about it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). For `null` or `undefined` values it returns `undefined`.

```
for (const item of someObj.someObjArray) {
    item.startDate = item.startDate?.split('T')[0];
}
```

Comment: Note that `?.` is compatible with most, but not all browsers (on May 14 2020). https://caniuse.com/#search=optional%20chaining

Comment: Angular is throwing an error with this saying "':' expected" after ?.split('T')[0];

Comment: Just saw that `caniuse` also says `1 Can be enabled by setting Experimental JavaScript to true`