# Is there something similar to the 'or operator' that treats 0 as a number instead of false?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple Vector class in Javascript, but since it doesn't support overloading, I experimented with the 'or operator' and came up with the following add function. It works with most inputs except for 0 since it's treated as false instead of a number by the 'or operator'. Is there something else similar in Javascript that I can use?

```
class Vector
{
    constructor(x,y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // possible inputs
    // - add(Vector)
    // - add(Number)
    // - add(Number,Number)
    add(parameter1,parameter2)
    {
        this.x += parameter1.x || parameter1;
        this.y += parameter1.y || parameter2 || parameter1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also relevant: [Is there a “null coalescing” operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/476436)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is the novel [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator which solves this particular issue.

However, [it is not supported in all browser versions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing).

Edit: NodeJs currently [does not support](https://node.green/#ES2020-features--nullish-coalescing-operator-----) nullish coalescing at all[image]

If you aren't restrained by any versions and can use it in your project, however, you're good to go.