# How to destructure a nested object only when it has a value?

Tags: javascript

```
  let notStudent, name, isRegistered
  if (studentDetail && studentDetail.fields) {
    ({ notStudent, name, isRegistered } = studentDetail.fields)
  }
```

Is there a way to write this logic without an if statement or in a succinct way?

Comment: ```const { fields: {notStudent, name, isRegistered }} = studentDetail```

Comment: `studentDetail ` is undefined in the code you posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can destructure in this way. The tricky thing is when there is no fields property on studentDetail then javascript can throw an error, to tackle that case, you can set default empty object using || operator.

```js
let studentDetail = {
  fields: {
    notStudent: '1',
    name: '2',
    isRegistered: true
  }
}

let {
  notStudent,
  name,
  isRegistered
} = (studentDetail && studentDetail.fields) || {};

console.log(notStudent);
console.log(name);
console.log(isRegistered);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can destructure an empty default object in case your `studentDetail.fields` doesn't exist:

```
const { notStudent, name, isRegistered } = studentDetail?.fields ?? {};
```

Comment: `const { notStudent, name, isRegistered } = studentDetail?.fields || {};` also work right? Is there any difference between `??` and `||`.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye Yes, [there is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/1048572), but if `fields` is always either `null`, `undefined` or an object, it probably doesn't matter.