# Value || '-', show 0 too

Tags: javascript, operators

I have a use case where I'm showing data from an API. If there is no data for that field, I'm showing a hyphen. in some cases where API returns 0 as a value, the UI would still show a hyphen.

```
const value = APIValue || '-'
```

In the above case, How do we show 0 instead of the hyphen when the input is 0?

Comment: Either use an actual condition or use the nullish coalescing operator `??` instead of `||`. I recommend the latter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: What type of values can you receive from that api?

Comment: @VLAZ, 0 ? 'True' : 'False' will always return false.

Comment: @Elanochecer, API always returns a number.

Comment: @visizky but `typeof value === "number" ? value : "-"` doesn't. As I said, using an *actual condition* - that isn't testing the truthiness of the value.

Comment: This would work if I don't change the API response value's type. In the case where API resp type for value would vary, it would always show hyphen.

Comment: OK, then make the condition whatever will match your API data. I am no longer sure what you're looking for - apparently you want a condition that somehow knows what your data is and forever would be and chooses the appropriate representation? Is it really impossible to do `value != null ? value : "-"` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either isNan or type checking the variable if you are expecting a number:

```js
const APIValue = 0;
const value = !isNaN(APIValue) ? APIValue : '-'

console.log(value)
```

```js
const APIValue = 0;
const value = typeof APIValue === "number" ? APIValue : "-";
console.log(value)
```

If you just want the variable to have any value you should check if its null, since this captures also undefined values:

```js
const APIValue = 0;
const value = APIValue != null ? APIValue : "-";
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
const value = APIValue || ((APIValue === 0) ? 0 : '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `null coalescing operator` or add if like one below:

```
If(APIValue === 0)
     return 0;
else
     return APIValue || '-'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const value = (APIValue == null ? '' : APIValue.toString()) || '-';
```