# Conditional concatenation in modern JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a neat way to conditionally concatenate strings.

See:

```js
const something = response.data
  .map(i => {
    const id = i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id
    return { image: id ? "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + id : undefined, ...i }
  })
```

I'd love to inline this, but can't find a way. Using null coelescing op like `('something' + foo) ?? undefined` is never resolved to undefined.

Edit: I'd like to minimise this to something like `.map(i => ({image: "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id, ...i}))` but `image` to be empty if there's no Id. I hope there's a neat trick somewhere.

Comment: What is the data-type and typical value of `data` and `i`? Are you using Promises, Observables/RxJS, or something else?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you're asking due to what is probably a bunch of unnecessary code. Are you just after a potentially shorter version of `id ? "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + id : undefined`?

Comment: Object with multiple props

Comment: Your current code looks quite reasonable to me

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks. Is CodeGolf more suitable forum?

Comment: @Phil added further explanation.

Comment: If you are not getting your undefined, you got to check the 'id' variable. Make sure id is a falsy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for shorthand to insert a variable into object if not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774661/looking-for-shorthand-to-insert-a-variable-into-object-if-not-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the *pain points* in most programming languages today is the inability - or difficulty - in expressing conditional string formatting operations (I wonder if this is a plot by language-designers to discourage us from using strings, after-all, strings *are* expensive and a PITA to manage without a GC). But as this is JavaScript, there's always the nuclear option: extending `String.prototype`:

```
String.prototype.p = a => this ? (a+this) : undefined;
```

Which means your code can retain its original form but be transformed to:

```
const something = response.data
  .map(i => {
    return { image: (i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id||'').p("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="), ...i }
  })
```

And then shortened again to:

```
const something = response.data
  .map(i => ({image: (i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id||'').p("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="), ...i }))
```

---

UPDATE: Now that I've slept on it, here's the IIFE version:

```
const something = response.data
  .map(i => ({image: (s=>s?("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="+s):undefined)(i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id), ...i }))
```

And shrink again once more for good luck:

```
const something = response.data.map(i=>({image:(s=>s?("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="+s):void 0)(i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id),...i}))
```

That's 135 characters total.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're looking for. You want to be able to reuse a complex expression inline without converting an expression-style arrow-function into a statement-style arrow function.
You can use expression assignment in those cases.

```
const answer = (x=complex_expression?.[0]?.Id, x && "long/string.With/stuff"+x);
```

Here's an example using that:

```
const something = response.data.map(i => ({
  image: (id=i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id, id && "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + id),
  ...i,
}));
```

And if you don't want the image key to be `null`, you can do this:

```
const something = response.data.map(i => ({
  ...(id=i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id, id && { image: "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + id}),
  ...i,
}));
```

Comment: "without converting an expression-style arrow-function into a statement-style arrow function" - I didn't infer thatr from the OP's post.

Comment: Hello global variables 

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
const something = response.data
  .map(i => ({ 
     image: i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id && "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id,          
     ...i 
     })
  );
```

Comment: This will result in the `image` property being defined, but having a nullish value when `i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id` is empty; whereas my understanding of the OP was that the `image` property should be omitted if empty/nullish.

Comment: FYI this is 29 characters longer than OP's code

Comment: @Dai no, OP has `undefined` as the fallback value for `image`. Unless `i.Attachments?.[0]` has an `Id` property that is _falsy_ but not `undefined`, this code will produce the same result

Comment: `i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id` could be an expensive operation (imagine `[].find()` instead) so I only want execute it once.

Comment: @dzh Why would that be "expensive"? It's just a dereference chain. It would only be expensive if the objects being passed-around have non-trivial property-getters, which is very unlikely (if not _impossible_) if these are just DTOs from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IIFE, but then we're getting silly. Alternatively, just another `map` layer does the trick:

```
const urlPrefix = "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=";

const something = response.data
    .map(i => ({ id: i.Attachments?.[0]?.Id, i }) )
    .map(t => ({ image: t.id ? (urlPrefix + t.id) : undefined, ...t.i }) );
```

Comment: Yep had this idea as well, but IMO solution in question is faster and easier to understand

Comment: @dzh Regarding performance, your "opinion" is irrelevant, what matters is actual benchmarks :) I'll be happy to profile my answer if you can provide us with raw data to benchmark against.

Comment: @Dai I imagine OP is referring to their _O(n)_ solution vs your _2O(n)_ one. The difference in real time is probably negligible

Comment: No doubt it won't really matter in practice. Readability will so my opinion still stands :)

Comment: @Phil I've removed the initial spread-operator. The time-complexity of my solution is still `O(n)` though - and note that the spread-operator in JavaScript _can_ be a `O(1)` operation if the engine uses deferred evaluation of merged objects, or even uses a linked-list structure instead of naively copying hashmap entries.

Comment: You have two map operations over the same data set, thus _2O(n)_. FYI, I wasn't the one who pointed out the `id` property thing but saw that you fixed it.

Comment: @Phil `2O(n)` isn't correct notation - and using `map` twice in succession does not necessarily result in two naïve iterations. There's a lot of crazy but valid optimizations in modern JS engines (source: I used to work on Chakra)