# Gatsby Config gives error in Javascript file for ?? operator

Tags: javascript, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to run a Gatsby site but when I do `npm run develop`, I am getting this error:

```
> gatsby develop

 ERROR #10123  CONFIG

We encountered an error while trying to load your site's gatsby-config. Please fix the error x try again.



  Error: D:\Coding\web-blog\src\infra\feed.js:28
  description: post.intro ?? post.description,
                           ^
```

Code:

```js
const item = {
                title: sanitizeTitle(post.title),
                description: post.intro ?? post.description,
                url: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}/${post.slug}`,
                guid: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}/${post.slug}`,
                categories: post.tags,
                author: site.siteMetadata.author,
                date: post.date,
            }
```

What is `??` operator in Javscript? Is it a new language feature?

Comment: _“What is this operator in Javascript?”_ — [The nullish coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/476436/4642212); see [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Comment: As for the error: make sure your environment understands ECMAScript 2020.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nullish coalescing operator (`??`) it's a feature from ECMAScript 2020 ([see TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing)). You can add it by [modifying the babel configuration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/babel/) or by installing the [`gatsby-plugin-nullish-coalescing-operator`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-nullish-coalescing-operator/) plugin.

If you choose the first version, add a `.babelrc` in the root of your project and populate it with the following:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"]
  ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "babel-preset-gatsby",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

*Note: you will need to install the [`@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) dependency.*

> What is this operator in Javascript?

The nullish coalescing operator (`??`), uses the right value if left is `null` or `undefined`. The main difference between the OR operator (`||`) is in the falsy values where it can lead to some errors while used in `""`, `0` or `false` values (there are more falsy values such as `-0`, `NaN`, etc but those are the common). So:

```
description: post.intro ?? post.description,
```

You will use `post.intro` as long as it exists, otherwise (if `post.intro` is `null` or `undefined`), you will use `post.description`.

Comment: Have tried adding `.babelrc` as well as gatsby plugin (via `npm install`) , still facing issue

Comment: Have you installed `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-gatsby` as the docs points? https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/babel/

Comment: Have added `package.json` to the question

Answer (score 3):

The `gatsby-config.js` file and any plugin code (or code it requires) isn't compiled by Babel before Gatsby loads it so any syntax you use must be supported by the version of Node.js you have installed. It looks like [the `??` operator is supported in Node.js 14+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) so check your version of Node by running `node --version`.

My favorite way of upgrading Node (as I'm guessing you'll need to do) is with https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Answer (score -1):

Add dependencies to use ES2020 features for null coalescing.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-gatsby
npm i gatsby-plugin-nullish-coalescing-operator @babel/core
```

Add `.babelrc` file with the following configurations:

```js
{
    "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"]
    ],
    "presets": [
      [
        "babel-preset-gatsby",
        {
          "targets": {
            "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Make sure you are running Node 14.x which supports ES2020 features